# Battle of the Fellowships KotH

Tags: king-of-the-hill, java

In this challenge, you are going to create a *Fellowship* with the goal of defeating all other fellowships in battle.

**A fellowship (team) consists of 3 characters**.  Each character moves independently of the rest of their team, but they will need to work together when fighting your enemy. Teams will face each other head to head in a rotating manner.  Wins are worth 3 points, ties are worth 1 point, and losses are worth 0 points.

Characters have Abilities. **The choice of what abilities your characters have is one of the most crucial (and fun) parts in this KotH**.  They are all strong, and have the potential to wipe out your enemy.

**Characters have Health Points (HP), and when their HP hits (or goes below) 0, they die**.  If all characters on your opponent's team dies, then you win!

**Characters have Mana.  Most actions require Mana to perform**, and if you don't have enough, that action is not available to you.

**Characters have a Turn Delay**.  This determines the number of ticks between each turn (starts out at 100).  Lower is better.

**Characters have attributes**.  Each character has a base of 5 in each attribute, and you are given 20 additional attribute points to divide up.  After assigning attribute points, your *primary attribute* is set as your highest attribute.

Available attributes are:

- Strength:  Gives 10 Max HP and .5 HP per turn
- Intelligence: Gives 7 Max Mana and .1 Mana per turn
- Agility: Reduces Turn Delay by 1

**Movement, Vision, Range**
Ranges are as follows (centered around the 0).  Some ranges are *cardinal*, which means that they can only go directly up, left, right, or down.

```
    444
   43334
  4322234
 432111234
 432101234
 432111234
  4322234
   43334
    444
```

Characters have a starting vision of 2.  Vision between players of the same fellowship is shared.

## How to play

**Construction**
Players will construct their fellowship.  **You need to do the following steps**:

1. **Give each character attribute points**.  Each character starts out with 5 in each stat, with an additional 20 to distribute between the 3.
2. **Give each character abilities**.  Each character starts out with 4 ability slots, and abilities take 1 slot by default.  Some abilities are *repeatable*, and can be given to a character multiple times.  Using an ability set of another submission without the owner's permission is not allowed.
3. **Write some code** for your bots.  The code must be in Java, and will be used for battling (the next step)

**Actions**

All characters start with the 3 standard actions:

1. *Step*: Move your character in a cardinal range of 1
2. *Slice*: Attack an enemy for *PrimaryAttribute* in a cardinal range of 1
3. *Smile*: Do nothing

On a characters' turn, then must pick an action to perform.  Actions may have a Mana cost, and may have a Cooldown, which defines the number of turns you have to wait before performing that action again.

**Abilities**
Every character has 4 ability slots.  If an ability is in italics, it is an action.

## Abilities

```
Name         Description                                                                Mana  Cooldown 
                                                    Mobility                                                     

Blink        Move to a square, range 4                                                     2         2 
Swap         Swap locations with Target                                                    5         5 
Teleport     Move anywhere                                                                20         5 

Dash         Increase the range of step by 1. Repeatable                                               
Mobile       Step can move in any of the 8 directions                                                  
                                                    Attacking                                                    

Quick        Slice twice                                                                   3         0 
Weave        Slice all visible enemies once                                               15        10 

Absorb       Each Slice steals 1 of your target's primary attribute. Lasts 20 turns                    
Cleave       Each Slice deals 1/2 damage to adjacent enemies                                           
Critital     Adds a 30% chance for Slice to deal 200% damage. Repeatable                               
Feast        Each Slice increases your HP by 3. Repeatable                                             
Flexible     Can Slice in any of the 8 directions                                                      
Mana steal   Slice steals 2 mana. Repeatable                                                           
Reflexive    Slice when sliced                                                             0         3 
Ranged       Adds 1 to the range of Slice                                                              
Swipe        Each consecutive Slice on the same target deals 3 more damage than the last               
                                                    Statuses                                                     

Dispel       Removes all statuses from a Target. Range 2.                                 20        10 
Duel         Freezes you and your target until one of you dies. Range 1                   25         0 
Knockout     You and target are stunned for the next 1000 ticks                           10        10 
Meteor       All enemies are stunned for the next 100 ticks                               25        10 
Leash        Target is frozen for their 2 next turns                                       4         6 
Poison       Poisons the enemy for 1 HP for 5 turns                                        5         0 
Silence      Target is silenced for 5 turns                                                5         7 
Slow         Target is slowed by 40 ticks for their next 3 turns                          10         5 
Stun         Target is stunned for the next 300 ticks                                     10        10 

Cold         All other characters within 2 range are slowed by 10 ticks                                
Immune       No status can be applied to you                                                           
                                                    Defensive                                                    

Force Field  Block next 5 sources of damage. Does not stack                               15         5 
Ghost        For a turn, all damage heals                                                 10        10 
Heal         Heal Target for 20 HP                                                        10         3 
Restore      All units are restored back to full health                                   20        40 
Shield       You cannot be Sliced until your next turn                                     3         0 

Evasive      25% chance for a Slice to not hit you. Repeatable                                         
Pillar       Only can be sliced once a turn                                                            
Resurrect    When killed, come back to life with full HP (and no statuses)                 0        40 
Spikes       When dealt damage, deal half of the damage back                                           
                                                     Vision                                                      

Cloak        Team becomes invisible for 5 turns                                           20        20 
Hide         You are invisible for 5 turns                                                 4         7 
Phase        Become invisible for 1 turn                                                   0         3 
Track        Target cannot go invisible, and takes 10% more damage. Lasts 10 turns.        5         5 

Darkness     Enemy sight range decreased by 1. Stacks, but cannot go below 1.                                 
Far sight    Sight range increased by 2. Repeatable                                                    
Invisible    You are invisible if you start your turn out of enemy vision                               
True sight   Reveals all hidden units within range 2 at turn start                                     
                                                     Damage                                                      

Drain        Deals 5 damage to Target and heals self for 5 HP while they stay in 1 range  10         5 
Lightning    Deal 15 damage to all enemies                                                20        10 
K/O          Kills target if target is below 20% HP                                       20         0 
Trap         Place an invisible trap. Trap deals 15 damage when stepped on. Stacks.       10         2 
Zap          Deal 30 damage to target                                                     30         5 

Static       Deals 5 damage every turn to all enemies within 1 range. Repeatable                       
                                                      Stats                                                      

Werewolf     Add 10 to all stats for 5 turns                                              30        25 

Buff         Double your HP pool. Repeatable                                                           
Clever       Actions have 20% shorter cooldown. Repeatable                                             
Focused      Increases your Mana regeration rate by Int/10. Repeatable                                  
Regenerate   Increases your Regneration rate by Strength/2. Repeatable                                 
Smart        Actions cost 2 less mana. Repeatable                                                      
Strong       You gain 10 attribute points. Repeatable                                                  
Weak         You lose 15 attribute points. You gain 2 ability slots (this takes one of them)                  
                                                      Other                                                      

Bear         Can summon a bear which has 5 in each stat                                    8        10 
Clone        Clone yourself. Takes two ability slots.                                    100       100 
Steal        Replace this action with last action enemy Target used. Lasts 10 turns        5         0 
Wall         Create an impassible wall on targetted empty square, range 6                 10        10
```

## Statuses:

- Stun allows your character to *only* perform the Smile action, and lasts X *ticks*.
- Freeze prevents your character from moving, and lasts X turns.
- Silence prevents your character from performing anything besides Smile, Step, or Slice, and lasts X turns.
- Poison damages your character for X damage for Y turns.  If you apply another poison, the damage adds together, and the duration is refreshed.
- Slow adds X to the number of ticks between your turns.  It does not affect your *upcoming* turn, only turns after.
- Invisible makes it so you cannot be seen or damaged by your opponent.  If you perform any action besides Step or Smile, it is removed.  If your opponent has an ability that gives them vision of you, invisibility is removed.

All statuses (except for Poison) act independently of each other.

## Side Notes:

- If there's a tie for the primary attribute, it is resolved as STR > AGI > INT.
- You play on a 10x10 grid.  Teams will be placed on opposite sides.
- Percentages stack multiplicatively, except for Clever.

## Submission rules

You need to implement 2 functions:

```
// Create *exactly* 3 Character templates.  You must return the same templates every time
public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters();

// Choose an action for a character.  If the action requires a target or location, it must be set.
public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character);
```

You'll also have access to three variables (member variables):

```
Set<ReadonlyCharacter> team;
Set<EnemyCharacter> enemies;
Map<Point2D, EnemyCharacter> visibleEnemies;
```

That's it.  Below you can find a complete API, in alphabetical order:

```
class Ability and ReadonlyAbility
    int getNumSlots() returns the number of slots it takes up
    boolean repeatable() returns true if the ability can be repeated
    String name()
class Action and ReadonlyAction
    Set<Point2D> availableLocations()
    Set<ReadonlyCharacter> availableTargets()
    boolean basicAction() returns true if the action is Smile, Step, or Slice
    boolean breaksInvisibiliby()      
    int getCooldown() returns the cooldown cost (not the cooldown remaining)
    int getManaCost()
    String getName()
    int getRemainingCooldown()
    boolean isAvailable() returns true if the action can be performed
    boolean movementAction() returns true if the action is prevented when Frozen
    boolean needsLocation()
    boolean needsTarget()
    void setTarget(ReadonlyCharacter target)
    void setLocation(Point2D location)
class CharacterTemplate
    void addAbility(Ability)
    boolean canAddAbility(Ability)
    List<Ability> currentAbilities()
    Map<Stat, Integer> currentAttributes()
    int getRemainingPoints() returns the total number of ability points you have left to assign
    int getRemainingSlots() returns the total number of slots you have to assign
    int getStat(Stat stat)
    boolean isValid() returns true if your character template is complete and valid
class Point2D
    getX()
    getY()
class Range
    boolean isCardinal() returns true if the range only extends in the 4 cardinal directions
    int getRange() returns the distance of the range
class ReadonlyCharacter and EnemyCharacter
    Class characterClass()
    int cleverness()
    List<ReadonlyAbility> getAbilities()
    Point2D getLocation()   Not on EnemyCharacter
    double getHealth()
    double getMana()
    int getMaxHealth()
    int getMaxMana()
    Range getSightRange()
    Range getSliceRange()
    int getStat(Stat stat)
    Range getStepRange()
    ReadonlyAction getLastAction()
    boolean isFrozen()
    boolean isStunned()
    boolean isPoisoned()
    int getPoisonAmount()
    boolean isSilenced()
    boolean isInvisible()
    boolean isDead()
    Stat primaryStat()
    int smartness()
enum Stat
    INT, STR, AGI
```

The above is all of the functions you could possibly need for your submission. Reflection is not allowed.  **If a submission is invalid for whatever reason, please remove it or add "Invalid" to the header.**  Your submission should *not* have a package declaration.  Your submission should be contained in the first multi-line code block, and the first line must have the file name.

## How to run the project:

There are several ways:

1. Download the [JAR file](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/releases/tag/1.0.0), and run `java -jar Fellowship.jar`.  If you want to download other submissions, pass `-q 99744`. `java` **must** point to the JDK, not the JRE.
2. Clone the [git repo](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship), and run `gradle run`. You need to have gradle installed, and if you want to pass arguments, use `-PappArgs="['arg1', 'args2']"`
3. Clone the [git repo](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship), and compile it yourself.  You will need the following libraries: `org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-api:8.0.0`,`org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections:8.0.0`,`com.beust:jcommander:1.48`,`com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7`,`org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2`

**If you clone you must use the `--recursive` flag, and when you pull updates, include `--recurse-submodules`** For any of the above, your class needs to go in the `submissions/java` folder.  If you are using gradle, or compiling it yourself, you can put the class in the project itself.  You will need to uncomment some lines in the main function, and update them to point to your class.

Scoreboard:

```
+------+-------------------+-------+
| Rank | Name              | Score |
+------+-------------------+-------+
|    1 | TheWalkingDead    | 738.0 |
|    2 | RogueSquad        | 686.0 |
|    3 | Spiky             | 641.0 |
|    4 | Invulnerables     | 609.0 |
|    5 | Noob              | 581.0 |
|    6 | Railbender        | 561.0 |
|    7 | Vampire           | 524.0 |
|    8 | LongSword         | 508.0 |
|    9 | SniperSquad       | 456.0 |
|   10 | BearCavalry       | 430.0 |
|   11 | StaticCloud       | 429.0 |
|   12 | PlayerWerewolf    | 388.0 |
|   13 | LongSwordv2       | 347.0 |
|   14 | Derailer          | 304.0 |
|   15 | Sorcerer          | 266.0 |
|   16 | CowardlySniperMk2 | 262.0 |
|   17 | TemplatePlayer    |  59.0 |
+------+-------------------+-------+
```

If you have any questions, or need help, comment below, or join [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48475/battle-of-the-fellowships)!  **Good luck and have fun**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48475/battle-of-the-fellowships).

Comment: Lightning is listed as `Deal 15 damage to all enemies`, but invisible enemies are unaffected by lightning. Is this a bug? Otherwise, invisibility seems pretty strong to me...

Comment: Invisibility says that "you cannot be seen or damaged".  Invisible *is* strong.  I've try to make everything strong, as long as they have their weaknesses.  In the case of invisibility, try True Sight, Track, or Trap.

Comment: This challenge is exceptionally more complex than previous such challenges. I wish there was a format here that made something like this more competitive over the long term.

Comment: It's maintained a good amout of activity despite it's age and receiving no answers for the first couple of days. I will continue to run this challenge as long as people are interested

Comment: I will be adding more bots. it is complex enough to have very diverse solutions. I will however be focusing on an alternative visualiser to help me (and maybe others?) develop a bot.

Comment: @Moogie you do know about -g right? If there is more information you want it to show, ask, and I'll see what I can do

Comment: Yep, do know if the -g options, however when i was developing my bot i had it was not yet in a usable state so i started making an alternative. It is very rudimentary at the moment but it does have visible sight radius. Here is a capture of Bear Cavalry vs Template player ![capture](http://imgur.com/download/CkBOsTj).

Comment: Can you test the new characters and update the score?

Answer (score 10):

## StaticCloud

A sentient growing cloud which does static damage to anybody coming close. It consists of:

- 1/3 **Invisible part**

  - **STR:** 5; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 25
  - **Clone**, **Invisible**, **Static**
- 2/3 **Visible part**

  - **STR:** 5; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 25
  - **Clone**, **Static**, **Static**

*You may reuse single characters from here in your team, as long as you add at least one more character which is not present here.*

```java
StaticCloud.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.ImmutableSet;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.factory.Sets;

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;

import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.damage.Static;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.Invisible;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class StaticCloud extends SleafarPlayer {
    private CharacterTemplate invisibleTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new Invisible(), new Static());
    }

    private CharacterTemplate visibleTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new Static(), new Static());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        return Arrays.asList(visibleTemplate(), invisibleTemplate(), visibleTemplate());
    }

    private class InvisibleCloud extends Character {
        protected InvisibleCloud(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            if (clone != null && (isVisible() || !isInEnemySightRange())) {
                int invisibleCount = countCharacters(InvisibleCloud.class);
                if (invisibleCount > 8 && setClosestSafeLocation(clone, getStaticLocations())) {
                    return clone;
                } else if (setCloneLocation(clone, invisibleCount < 3 ? 3 : 1)) {
                    return clone;
                }
            }
            if (step != null && isVisible() && isInEnemySliceRange() &&
                    setClosestSafeLocation(step, getStaticLocations())) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && isVisible() && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null) {
                ImmutableSet<Point2D> avoidLocations = !isVisible() || isInEnemySliceRange() ?
                        Sets.immutable.empty() : getEnemySliceLocations();
                if ((isVisible() || clone != null) && !getEnemyHiddenLocations().isEmpty() &&
                        setClosestLocation(step, avoidLocations, getEnemyHiddenLocations())) {
                    return step;
                }
                if (!getStaticLocations().contains(getLocation()) &&
                        setClosestLocation(step, avoidLocations, getStaticLocations())) {
                    return step;
                }
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    private class VisibleCloud extends Character {
        protected VisibleCloud(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            if (clone != null) {
                int visibleCount = countCharacters(VisibleCloud.class);
                if (visibleCount > 5 && setClosestSafeLocation(clone, getStaticLocations())) {
                    return clone;
                } else if (setCloneLocation(clone, visibleCount < 3 ? 2 : 1)) {
                    return clone;
                }
            }
            if (step != null && isInEnemySliceRange() && setClosestSafeLocation(step, getStaticLocations())) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && !getStaticLocations().contains(getLocation())) {
                if (isInEnemySliceRange() ? setClosestLocation(step, getStaticLocations()) :
                        setClosestSafeLocation(step, getStaticLocations())) {
                    return step;
                }
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
        if (hasAbility(delegate, Invisible.class)) {
            return new InvisibleCloud(delegate);
        } else {
            return new VisibleCloud(delegate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is interesting because Static doesn't break invisibility.

Answer (score 7):

## Template Player

Uses **Ranged**, **Flexible**, **Zap**, and **KO**.  You have permission to use this ability set if you wish.

Feel free to use this bot as a template for creating your own.

Remember that you need to change the filename on the first line, as well as selecting your own ability set.

```
TemplatePlayer.java
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Flexible;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Ranged;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.damage.KO;
import fellowship.actions.damage.Zap;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.Player;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TemplatePlayer extends Player{
    private final double CRITICAL_HEALTH = 20;
    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(10, 5, 5,
                    new Ranged(),
                    new Flexible(),
                    new ActionAbility(KO::new),
                    new ActionAbility(Zap::new)));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        int minPriority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ReadonlyAction chosen = null;
        for (ReadonlyAction action: actions){
            int priority = getPriorityFor(action, character);
            if (priority < minPriority){
                chosen = action;
                minPriority = priority;
            }
        }
        if (chosen == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }
        if (chosen.needsLocation()){
            chosen.setLocation(chooseLocationFor(chosen, character));
        } else if (chosen.needsTarget()){
            chosen.setTarget(chooseTargetFor(chosen));
        }
        return chosen;
    }

    private Point2D chooseLocationFor(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (action.movementAction()){
            if (character.getHealth() < CRITICAL_HEALTH){
                return fromEnemy(action.availableLocations());
            } else {
                return toEnemy(action.availableLocations());
            }
        }
        return toTeam(action.availableLocations());
    }

    private Point2D toEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private Point2D fromEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.maxBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private Point2D toTeam(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (team.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(team.collect(ReadonlyCharacter::getLocation).minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private ReadonlyCharacter chooseTargetFor(ReadonlyAction action){
        return action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth);
    }

    private int getPriorityFor(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (character.isInvisible() && action.breaksInvisibility()){
            return 1000;
        }
        if (action.getName().equals("Smile")){
            return 999;
        }
        if (action.movementAction()){
            if (character.getHealth() < 20){
                return 0;
            }
            return 998;
        }
        if (action.needsTarget()) {
            return ((int) action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth).getHealth());
        }
        return 997;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## CowardlySniperMk2

Uses **Zap**, **FarSight** *2, and **Hide**.

This bot is a coward. Its highest priority is not to be targeted. To that end he uses its superior sight to see where enemies are. It uses this knowledge to avoid being seen whilst tracking/following the enemy with out being seen. If it is seen, or could be seen in the next turn then the bot will 'hide' becoming invisible for a time.

In tracking mode, and there is sufficient mana and cooldown reset, then will 'Zap' the weakest visible enemy.

Once mana is down to 10% then will shy away from enemies until mana is restored. In this way, it can zap as fast as possible on tracked enemy. Hopefully negating any HP regen the enemy has.

Note since 'Zap' is infinite range, team members will all target the same bot when zapping.

I have other varients of this same basic idea that I may add as answers: they all have differing benefits/detriments that are exploited/exposed depending on the opponents present.

```java
CowardlySniperMk2.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.FarSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.damage.Zap;
import fellowship.actions.vision.Hide;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import fellowship.*;

public class CowardlySniperMk2 extends Player{

    private final static boolean DEBUG=false; 
    private static Point2D lastAttackedEnemyLocation = null;
    private static HashMap<ReadonlyCharacter, Boolean> rechargingManaMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final double STANDARD_VISION_MOVEMENT_BUFFER = 3;
    private final double MIN_VISION_DISTANCE = 2;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(8, 8, 4,
                    new ActionAbility(Zap::new),
                    new FarSight(),
                    new FarSight(),
                    new ActionAbility(Hide::new)));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        
        // get last flag for recharging mana
        Boolean rechargingMana = rechargingManaMap.get(character);
        if (rechargingMana == null || rechargingMana)
        {
            rechargingMana = !(character.getMana()>0.90*character.getMaxMana());
        }
        else
        {
            rechargingMana = character.getMana()<0.10*character.getMaxMana();
        }
        
        rechargingManaMap.put(character,rechargingMana);
        
        HashMap<Integer, ReadonlyAction> validActions = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> actionString = new HashMap<>();
        
        // see if we have arrived at the last attack location of the enemy
        if (character.getLocation().equals(lastAttackedEnemyLocation))
        {
            lastAttackedEnemyLocation = null;
        }

        double closestEnemyVisionDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for ( Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keySet())
        {
            final int enemyVisibiltyRange = visibleEnemies.get(enemyLocation).getSightRange().getRange();
            double visionDistanceDiff = character.getLocation().diagonalDistance(enemyLocation)-enemyVisibiltyRange;
            if (visionDistanceDiff< closestEnemyVisionDistance)
            {
                closestEnemyVisionDistance = visionDistanceDiff;
            }
        }
        
        for (ReadonlyAction action: actions){
            
            int priority=-1;
            String message = "";
            switch (action.getName())
            {
                case "Hide":
                    // are we, or will we be within sight range of an enemy
                    if (closestEnemyVisionDistance < STANDARD_VISION_MOVEMENT_BUFFER )
                    {
                        if (!character.isInvisible())
                        {
                            message = ""+closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                            priority = 1000;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            
                case "Step":
                    
                    Point2D chosenLocation = null;
                
                    // are we within sight range of an enemy or are we recharging mana?
                    if (closestEnemyVisionDistance < MIN_VISION_DISTANCE || rechargingMana)
                    {
                        message = "Fleeing (Seen) "+ closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                        priority = 800;
                        
                        if (character.isInvisible())
                        {
                            message = "Fleeing (UnSeen) "+ closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                            priority = 500;
                        }
                        
                        // simple enemy avoidance... chose location that is farthest away from closest enemy
                        double furthestDistance = 0;
                        
                        for ( Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keySet())
                        {
                            for (Point2D location : action.availableLocations())
                            {
                                if (location.diagonalDistance(enemyLocation) > furthestDistance)
                                {
                                    furthestDistance = location.diagonalDistance(enemyLocation);
                                    chosenLocation = location;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (chosenLocation == null)
                        {
                            // no moves are better than staying in current location
                            priority = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // are we "tracking" an enemy?
                    else if (lastAttackedEnemyLocation !=null)
                    {
                        priority = 20;
                        message = "Tracking "+ closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                        
                        // head toward last attacked enemy location
                        double distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        for (Point2D location : action.availableLocations())
                        {
                            if (location.diagonalDistance(lastAttackedEnemyLocation) < distance)
                            {
                                distance = location.diagonalDistance(lastAttackedEnemyLocation);
                                chosenLocation = location;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // are we outside the sight range of all enemies?
                    else if (closestEnemyVisionDistance > STANDARD_VISION_MOVEMENT_BUFFER)
                    {
                        // scout for an enemy
                        
                        priority = 10;
                        message = "Scouting "+ closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                        
                        // dumb random location selection... not optimal but is sufficent.
                        int index = getRandom().nextInt(action.availableLocations().size());
                        for (Point2D location : action.availableLocations())
                        {
                            chosenLocation= location;
                            if (--index == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // we are in the sweet zone... just out of enemy sight range but within our sight range
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    action.setLocation(chosenLocation);
                    break;
                
                case "Zap":
                    message = ""+closestEnemyVisionDistance;
                    ReadonlyCharacter chosenTarget = null;
                    double chosenTargetHealth = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    
                    // target the weakest enemy
                    for (ReadonlyCharacter target : action.availableTargets())
                    {
                        if (target.getHealth() < chosenTargetHealth)
                        {
                            chosenTargetHealth = target.getHealth();
                            chosenTarget = target;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (chosenTarget != null)
                    {
                        priority = 100;
                        action.setTarget(chosenTarget);
                        lastAttackedEnemyLocation = chosenTarget.getLocation();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // nothing to target
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Smile":
                    priority = 0;
                    break;
            }
            
            // add the action to the collection of valid actions to perform
            if (priority >-1)
            {
                validActions.put(priority, action);
                actionString.put(priority, message);
            }
            
        }
        

        int highestPriority = -1;
        ReadonlyAction chosen = null;
        
        // choose the highest priority action
        for (Integer priority : validActions.keySet())
        {
            if (priority > highestPriority)
            {
                highestPriority = priority;
                chosen = validActions.get(priority);
            }
        }
        String message = actionString.get(highestPriority);
        
        if (chosen == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }
        
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(this+"("+System.identityHashCode(character)+"): "+chosen.getName()+ (rechargingMana?" Mana_charge":" Mana_usable")+" H: "+character.getHealth()+" M: "+character.getMana() +(character.isInvisible()?" InVis":" Vis") +" x: "+character.getLocation().getX()+" y: "+character.getLocation().getY()+" "+message);
        return chosen;
    }
}
```

Comment: The filename should be CowardlySniperMk2 :)

Comment: oops :P cut and paste makes me look like a fool!

Comment: Reminds me of MarioKart Wii's B Dasher MK2 :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Reminds me of Splatoon's Bamboozler 14 Mk II. ;)

Answer (score 7):

## RogueSquad

A rogue squad consists of:

- 1 **Scout** (stays in shadows while exploring the map)

  - **STR:** 5; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 25
  - **Clone**, **Invisible**, **Far sight**
- 2 **Assasins** (attack enemies with deadly poison)

  - **STR:** 5; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 25
  - **Clone**, **Poison**, **Focused**

The by far biggest power both can use, is to call additional members of the squad to support them.

*You may reuse single characters from here in your team, as long as you add at least one more character which is not present here.*

```java
RogueSquad.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Focused;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.FarSight;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.Invisible;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.actions.statuses.Poison;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class RogueSquad extends SleafarPlayer {
    private CharacterTemplate scoutTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new Invisible(), new FarSight());
    }

    private CharacterTemplate assasinTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new ActionAbility(Poison::new), new Focused());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        return Arrays.asList(assasinTemplate(), scoutTemplate(), assasinTemplate());
    }

    private class Scout extends Character {
        protected Scout(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            if (clone != null && (isVisible() || !isInEnemySightRange()) && setCloneLocation(clone, 3)) {
                return clone;
            }
            if (step != null && isVisible() && isInEnemySliceRange() && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && isVisible() && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && isVisible() && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (step != null && !isVisible() && setExploreLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    private class Assasin extends Character {
        protected Assasin(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            ReadonlyAction poison = getAction(Poison.class);
            if (clone != null && setCloneLocation(clone, 1)) {
                return clone;
            }
            if (step != null && isInEnemySliceRange() && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (poison != null && setPoisonTarget(poison)) {
                return poison;
            }
            if (step != null && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
        if (hasAbility(delegate, Invisible.class)) {
            return new Scout(delegate);
        } else if (hasAbility(delegate, Poison.class)) {
            return new Assasin(delegate);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Base class for all my bots

```java
SleafarPlayer.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.eclipse.collections.api.RichIterable;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.map.ImmutableMap;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.map.MutableMap;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.ImmutableSet;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.tuple.Pair;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.factory.Maps;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.factory.Sets;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.list.primitive.IntInterval;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.tuple.Tuples;

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;

import fellowship.Player;
import fellowship.Range;
import fellowship.abilities.ReadonlyAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Critical;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Reflexive;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.Spikes;
import fellowship.abilities.statuses.Immune;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Slice;
import fellowship.actions.mobility.Step;
import fellowship.actions.other.Smile;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterInterface;
import fellowship.characters.EnemyCharacter;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public abstract class SleafarPlayer extends Player {
    private static final ImmutableSet<Point2D> MAP_LOCATIONS = IntInterval.fromTo(0, 9)
            .collect(x -> IntInterval.fromTo(0, 9).collect(y -> new Point2D(x, y))).flatCollect(t -> t).toSet()
            .toImmutable();
    protected static final Comparator<CharacterInterface> HEALTH_COMPARATOR = (o1, o2) ->
            Double.compare(o1.getHealth(), o2.getHealth());
    private static final Range BLOCKING_RANGE = new Range(1, true);
    private static final Range STATIC_RANGE = new Range(1);

    protected static boolean hasAbility(CharacterInterface character, Class<?> ability) {
        return character.getAbilities().anySatisfy(a -> a.abilityClass().equals(ability));
    }

    protected static boolean isBear(CharacterInterface character) {
        return character.getAbilities().isEmpty();
    }

    protected static double calcSliceDamage(CharacterInterface character) {
        return character.getStat(character.primaryStat()) * (hasAbility(character, Quick.class) ? 2.0 : 1.0);
    }

    protected static boolean setLocation(ReadonlyAction action, Point2D location) {
        if (location != null) {
            action.setLocation(location);
        }
        return location != null;
    }

    protected static boolean setTarget(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter target) {
        if (target != null) {
            action.setTarget(target);
        }
        return target != null;
    }

    protected abstract class Character {
        protected final ReadonlyCharacter delegate;

        protected Character(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super();
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        protected abstract ReadonlyAction choose();

        protected double getHealth() {
            return delegate.getHealth();
        }

        protected double getHealthRegen() {
            return delegate.getHealthRegen();
        }

        protected double getMana() {
            return delegate.getMana();
        }

        protected double getManaRegen() {
            return delegate.getManaRegen();
        }

        protected Point2D getLocation() {
            return delegate.getLocation();
        }

        protected boolean isVisible() {
            return !delegate.isInvisible();
        }

        protected double getSliceDamage() {
            return delegate.getStat(delegate.primaryStat());
        }

        protected boolean isInEnemySliceRange() {
            return getEnemySliceLocations().contains(delegate.getLocation());
        }

        protected boolean isInEnemySightRange() {
            return getEnemySightLocations().contains(delegate.getLocation());
        }

        protected boolean isInEnemyStepSightRange() {
            return getEnemyStepSightLocations().contains(delegate.getLocation());
        }

        protected double calcSliceRetaliationDamage(CharacterInterface character) {
            double result = 0.0;
            double ownDamage = getSliceDamage();
            for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
                if (ability.abilityClass().equals(Critical.class)) {
                    ownDamage = ownDamage * 2;
                }
            }
            for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
                if (ability.abilityClass().equals(Spikes.class)) {
                    result += ownDamage / 2.0;
                } else if (ability.abilityClass().equals(Reflexive.class)) {
                    result += character.getStat(character.primaryStat());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected double calcSpellRetaliationDamage(CharacterInterface character, double ownDamage) {
            double result = 0.0;
            for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
                if (ability.abilityClass().equals(Spikes.class)) {
                    result += ownDamage / 2.0;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected boolean setRandomLocation(ReadonlyAction action) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseRandom(action.availableLocations()));
        }

        protected boolean setRandomLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> avoidLocations) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseRandom(action.availableLocations().difference(avoidLocations)));
        }

        protected boolean setClosestLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> targetLocations) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseClosest(action.availableLocations(), targetLocations));
        }

        protected boolean setClosestLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> avoidLocations,
                ImmutableSet<Point2D> targetLocations) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseClosest(action.availableLocations().difference(avoidLocations),
                    targetLocations));
        }

        protected boolean setClosestHiddenLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> preferredLocations) {
            return setClosestLocation(action, getEnemySightLocations(), preferredLocations);
        }

        protected boolean setClosestSafeLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> preferredLocations) {
            return setClosestLocation(action, getEnemySliceLocations(), preferredLocations);
        }

        protected boolean setFarthestLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> targetLocations) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseFarthest(action.availableLocations(), targetLocations));
        }

        protected boolean setFarthestLocation(ReadonlyAction action, ImmutableSet<Point2D> avoidLocations,
                ImmutableSet<Point2D> targetLocations) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseFarthest(action.availableLocations().difference(avoidLocations),
                    targetLocations));
        }

        public boolean setCloneLocation(ReadonlyAction action, int distance) {
            ImmutableSet<Point2D> cloneLocations = distance < 2 ? team.collect(t -> t.getLocation()).toImmutable() :
                team.flatCollect(t -> t.rangeAround(new Range(distance))).difference(
                team.flatCollect(t -> t.rangeAround(new Range(distance - 1)))).toImmutable();
            if (cloneLocations.isEmpty()) {
                return setRandomLocation(action, getEnemySightLocations()) ||
                        setRandomLocation(action, getEnemySliceLocations()) ||
                        setRandomLocation(action);
            } else {
                return setClosestLocation(action, getEnemySightLocations(), cloneLocations) ||
                        setClosestLocation(action, getEnemySliceLocations(), cloneLocations) ||
                        setClosestLocation(action, cloneLocations);
            }
        }

        protected boolean setAvoidEnemiesLocation(ReadonlyAction action) {
            Point2D location = chooseFarthest(Sets.mutable.ofAll(action.availableLocations())
                    .with(delegate.getLocation()).difference(getEnemySliceLocations()), getEnemyLocations());
            if (location == null || location.equals(delegate.getLocation())) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return setLocation(action, location);
            }
        }

        protected boolean setBlockEnemiesLocation(ReadonlyAction action) {
            return setLocation(action, chooseRandom(action.availableLocations().intersect(getEnemyBlockingLocations())));
        }

        protected boolean setExploreLocation(ReadonlyAction action) {
            return visibleEnemies.size() < enemies.size() && getTeamHiddenLocations().notEmpty() &&
                    setClosestLocation(action, getEnemyStepSightLocations(), getTeamHiddenLocations());
        }

        protected boolean setSliceTarget(ReadonlyAction action, double minHealthReserve) {
            MutableSet<Pair<ReadonlyCharacter, Double>> pairs = action.availableTargets()
                    .collect(t -> Tuples.pair(t, calcSliceRetaliationDamage(t)));
            Pair<ReadonlyCharacter, Double> smallest = chooseSmallest(pairs, (o1, o2) -> {
                int c = Double.compare(o1.getTwo(), o2.getTwo());
                return c == 0 ? Double.compare(o1.getOne().getHealth(), o2.getOne().getHealth()) : c;
            });
            if (smallest == null || smallest.getTwo() > delegate.getHealth() - minHealthReserve) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return setTarget(action, smallest.getOne());
            }
        }

        protected boolean setPoisonTarget(ReadonlyAction action) {
            return setTarget(action, chooseSmallest(action.availableTargets().reject(c -> hasAbility(c, Immune.class)),
                    HEALTH_COMPARATOR));
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemyLocations() {
            if (enemyLocations == null) {
                enemyLocations = visibleEnemies.keysView().toSet().toImmutable();
            }
            return enemyLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemySliceLocations() {
            if (enemySliceLocations == null) {
                enemySliceLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(c.getTwo().getSliceRange(), c.getOne())).toSet()
                        .toImmutable();
            }
            return enemySliceLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemySightLocations() {
            if (enemySightLocations == null) {
                enemySightLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(c.getTwo().getSightRange(), c.getOne())).toSet()
                        .toImmutable();
            }
            return enemySightLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemyStepSightLocations() {
            if (enemyStepSightLocations == null) {
                enemyStepSightLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> Sets.mutable.ofAll(c.getTwo().rangeAround(c.getTwo().getStepRange(), c.getOne()))
                                .with(c.getOne()).flatCollect(r -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(c.getTwo().getSightRange(), r)))
                        .toSet().toImmutable();
            }
            return enemyStepSightLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemyHiddenLocations() {
            if (enemyHiddenLocations == null) {
                enemyHiddenLocations = MAP_LOCATIONS.difference(getEnemySightLocations());
            }
            return enemyHiddenLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getEnemyBlockingLocations() {
            if (enemyBlockingLocations == null) {
                enemyBlockingLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(BLOCKING_RANGE, c.getOne())).toSet().toImmutable();
            }
            return enemyBlockingLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getTeamHiddenLocations() {
            if (teamHiddenLocations == null) {
                teamHiddenLocations = MAP_LOCATIONS.difference(team.flatCollect(c -> c.rangeAround(c.getSightRange())));
            }
            return teamHiddenLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getTeamBlockingLocations() {
            if (teamBlockingLocations == null) {
                teamBlockingLocations = team.flatCollect(c -> c.rangeAround(BLOCKING_RANGE)).toImmutable();
            }
            return teamBlockingLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getSliceLocations() {
            if (sliceLocations == null) {
                sliceLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(delegate.getSliceRange(), c.getOne())).toSet().toImmutable();
            }
            return sliceLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableSet<Point2D> getStaticLocations() {
            if (staticLocations == null) {
                staticLocations = visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()
                        .flatCollect(c -> c.getTwo().rangeAround(STATIC_RANGE, c.getOne())).toSet().toImmutable();
            }
            return staticLocations;
        }

        protected final ImmutableMap<Point2D, Double> getEnemySliceDamage() {
            if (enemySliceDamage == null) {
                MutableMap<Point2D, Double> tmp = MAP_LOCATIONS.toMap(l -> l, l -> 0.0);
                for (Pair<Point2D, EnemyCharacter> p : visibleEnemies.keyValuesView()) {
                    double damage = calcSliceDamage(p.getTwo());
                    for (Point2D l : p.getTwo().rangeAround(p.getTwo().getSliceRange(), p.getOne())) {
                        tmp.put(l, tmp.get(l) + damage);
                    }
                }
                enemySliceDamage = tmp.toImmutable();
            }
            return enemySliceDamage;
        }
    }

    protected ImmutableMap<ReadonlyCharacter, Character> characters = Maps.immutable.empty();

    private ImmutableMap<Class<?>, ReadonlyAction> actions = null;
    protected ReadonlyAction step = null;
    protected ReadonlyAction slice = null;
    protected ReadonlyAction smile = null;

    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemyLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemySliceLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemySightLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemyStepSightLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemyHiddenLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> enemyBlockingLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> teamHiddenLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> teamBlockingLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> sliceLocations = null;
    private ImmutableSet<Point2D> staticLocations = null;
    private ImmutableMap<Point2D, Double> enemySliceDamage = null;

    protected final <T> T chooseRandom(Collection<T> collection) {
        if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
            int i = getRandom().nextInt(collection.size());
            for (T t : collection) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    return t;
                }
                --i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected final <T> T chooseSmallest(Collection<T> collection, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T t : collection) {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(t);
                } else {
                    int c = comparator.compare(t, list.get(0));
                    if (c < 0) {
                        list.clear();
                    }
                    if (c <= 0) {
                        list.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            return list.get(getRandom().nextInt(list.size()));
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected final Point2D chooseClosest(Collection<Point2D> available, RichIterable<Point2D> targets) {
        if (targets.isEmpty()) {
            return chooseRandom(available);
        } else {
            Map<Point2D, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (Point2D a : available) {
                map.put(a, targets.collect(t -> t.cartesianDistance(a)).min());
            }
            return chooseSmallest(available, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(map.get(o1), map.get(o2)));
        }
    }

    protected final Point2D chooseFarthest(Collection<Point2D> available, RichIterable<Point2D> targets) {
        if (targets.isEmpty()) {
            return chooseRandom(available);
        } else {
            Map<Point2D, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (Point2D a : available) {
                map.put(a, targets.collect(t -> t.cartesianDistance(a)).min());
            }
            return chooseSmallest(available, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(map.get(o2), map.get(o1)));
        }
    }

    protected int countCharacters(Class<?> clazz) {
        return characters.count(c -> c.getClass().equals(clazz));
    }

    protected ReadonlyAction getAction(Class<?> clazz) {
        return actions.get(clazz);
    }

    protected abstract Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate);

    @Override
    public final ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        characters = team.collect(c -> characters.getIfAbsentWith(c, this::createCharacter, c))
                .groupByUniqueKey(c -> c.delegate).toImmutable();

        this.actions = Sets.immutable.ofAll(actions).groupByUniqueKey(ReadonlyAction::actionClass);
        step = getAction(Step.class);
        slice = getAction(Slice.class);
        smile = getAction(Smile.class);

        enemyLocations = null;
        enemySliceLocations = null;
        enemySightLocations = null;
        enemyStepSightLocations = null;
        enemyHiddenLocations = null;
        enemyBlockingLocations = null;
        teamHiddenLocations = null;
        teamBlockingLocations = null;
        sliceLocations = null;
        staticLocations = null;
        enemySliceDamage = null;

        return characters.get(character).choose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. A tough team to beat... challenge accepted :P

Answer (score 7):

## The Invulnerables

A team of hardy warriors who can survive almost everything. This leads to a lot of timeouts, which unfortunately I often don't win. However, no matchup I've seen is unwinnable, and when the team loses, it's frequently with characters still surviving.

This team's hardest matchups are against the Bear Cavalry (they are literally incapable of wiping this team, but normally win on the tiebreak due to their sheer numbers); the Rogue Squad (the team is somewhat weak to poison); and the Vampire (I'm not entirely sure why yet).

In simulations, the team nearly always comes first or second. Its score is pretty stable; the winner normally depends on how well Rogue Squad does against the other competitors (its placement is a lot more random than the Invulnerables' is).

### The Mage in the Noxious Sphere

- **STR**: 5; **AGI**: 5; **INT**: 25

The Mage protects itself via using the combo of **Pillar** and **Force Field**; being **Focused** and having a high Intelligence, it regenerates enough mana to cast Force Field on cooldown each time. Assuming that the opponents don't have a boosted Agility, they can thus hit it with at most five Slices per five turns, and five damage sources will be blocked over that time period. In other words, the Mage absolutely requires spells to defeat; Slicing doesn't work by itself no matter how good at it you are.

The Mage can attack via Slicing for 25 in an emergency, but mostly casts **Poison** repeatedly, which is very spammable with an MP regeneration this high. Because Poison has an infinite range, limited only by the team's vision, the Mage is the way this team beats very HP-heavy or regenerative enemies; the rest of the team maintains vision on them, while the Mage deals quadratic amounts of damage. The poison inevitably ends up outpacing their HP regeneration eventually, and I don't have to worry about static damage such as Spikes in the process.

### The Giant Clifftop Falconer

- **STR**: 35; **AGI**: 5; **INT**: 5

The Falconer's main job is to get the rest of the team vision of targets, so that they can be attacked, scouting the map with the eyes of a falcon. **Far Sight** gives enough vision that enemies who try to hide or run away can normally be trapped by the vision range in a corner of the map; it's not very easy to give the Falconer the runaround. **True Sight** is this team's main recourse against invisible enemies, who would otherwise be impossible to damage. Being large, and thus **Strong**, makes the Falconer very resistant to damage, and capable of heavy Slices when necessary. Finally, the Falconer can release its falcons on the enemy crowds below, ordering them to **Weave** among the enemy and dealing massive (35) area damage.

In addition to the Falconer's job hunting down evasive enemies, and maintaining vision of enemies so that the Mage can keep poisoning them, the ability to occasionally Weave for 35 is key to dealing with enemy swarm teams; it's possible to hit a lot of enemies that way, and leave them low enough for the rest of the team to finish (ideally with another Weave). Swarming is pretty much an overpowered strategy under these rules, and Weave is one of the few real counters it has. Even then, it's not really good enough by itself.

### Trollbone Skullrender

- **STR**: 25; **AGI**: 5; **INT**: 5

Trollbone's job is to keep the enemy hordes suppressed while the other units can do their job. Just like the Mage, Trollbone has an infinite-range spell in **Knockout**. This combos very well with the Mage's Poison; if it's ever possible to face the enemy one-by-one (and against many teams, it is), the Falconer will gain vision, Trollbone will stun them, then the Mage will stack poison on them, and they'll end up dead without the ability to do anything (Knockout lasts 1000 ticks on the target and Trollbone's regenerates the cooldown for it slightly faster than that). It's also very good at protecting Trollbone against single strong enemies; they can't do anything to him if they aren't conscious. Of course, smashing skulls with an enemy is liable to leave both concussed, but Trollbone is **Immune** to stun and poison (and a bunch of other statuses nobody cares about). As a spell-focused character who nonetheless is not very magically inclined, Trollbone regenerates magic not through intelligence, but through drinking the blood of his enemies, doing a **Mana Steal** with every hit; this gives a pretty good rate of MP regeneration (and stunned enemies make easy targets to steal MP from). Finally, Trollbone occasionally goes on a rampage and will **Weave** through the enemy ranks while smashing their heads in and drinking their blood. Against a sufficiently large swarm of enemies, this actually regains mana, and it can finish off a swarm that the Falconer weakened (25 + 35 is 60, so it works even if the enemies regenerated to some extent in between).

### Strategy

Unlike many teams, I put a lot of focus into the AI, not just the teambuilding. One fundamental rule is that the team will always try to group if they aren't busy doing something else, making it harder for them to get surrounded and able to defend each other. If they're being swarmed, they'll try to hide in a corner. On the other hand, if the enemy tries to flee or run away, they roam the map, picking and pathing to random corners or the centre; this more or less guarantees that the Falconer will spot a target eventually. The movement is designed to never let the enemy get the first strike if possible; the enemy will have to walk into Slice range themself. The Mage will *always* leave up MP for Force Field, preventing a loss to MP exhaustion (the only way this can fail is with Absorb, which can get through a Force Field even if the damage doesn't). This isn't normally a problem; usually the Mage can spam Poison every turn without issues. If not intefered with, the team prefers to chase down enemies one at a time, stunning them when they come into vision, then poisoning them repeatedly until they die. With other enemies around, the team will try to kite them if possible, running around in circles and forcing most of the enemies to chase, while stunning and poisoning one of them. The main problem is with swarms, which is why there's so much Weaving here, but even then it seems hard to actually beat the strategy.

```java
Invulnerables.java
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.*;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.*;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.*;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.*;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.*;
import fellowship.abilities.statuses.*;
import fellowship.actions.*;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.*;
import fellowship.actions.damage.*;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.*;
import fellowship.actions.statuses.*;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.characters.EnemyCharacter;
import fellowship.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Invulnerables extends Player {
  @Override
  public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
    List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();

    templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                                        new ActionAbility(Poison::new),
                                        new ActionAbility(ForceField::new),
                                        new Focused(),
                                        new Pillar()));

    templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(30, 0, 0,
                                        new ActionAbility(Weave::new),
                                        new Strong(),
                                        new FarSight(),
                                        new TrueSight()));

    templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                                        new ActionAbility(Weave::new),
                                        new ActionAbility(Knockout::new),
                                        new ManaSteal(),
                                        new Immune()));

    return templates;
  }

  private String lastIdentifier(String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("\\W");
    return split[split.length - 1];
  }

  private boolean hasAbility(ReadonlyCharacter character, String abilityName) {
    for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
      if (lastIdentifier(ability.name()).equals(abilityName))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean hasAbility(EnemyCharacter character, String abilityName) {
    for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
      if (lastIdentifier(ability.name()).equals(abilityName))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private int getSquareDanger(ReadonlyCharacter character, Point2D square) {
    /* A square's danger is basically equal to the number of hits we'd
       expect to take when standing there. Each hit is worth 1; a hit of
       25 damage or more is worth 2. */
    int sliceDanger = 0;
    int otherDanger = 0;
    int cx = square.getX();
    int cy = square.getY();
    for (Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keysView()) {
      EnemyCharacter enemy = visibleEnemies.get(enemyLocation);
      if (enemy.isStunned())
        continue; /* approaching stunned enemies is a good thing */
      int dx = enemyLocation.getX() - cx;
      int dy = enemyLocation.getY() - cy;
      if (dx < 0)
        dx = -dx;
      if (dy < 0)
        dy = -dy;
      if (dx + dy <= 1) {
        /* We're in Static range. */
        if (hasAbility(enemy, "Static"))
          otherDanger++;
      }
      if (dx + dy <= enemy.getSliceRange().getRange() &&
          (dx * dy == 0 || !enemy.getSliceRange().isCardinal())) {
        int sliceMultiplier = 1;
        if (hasAbility(enemy, "Quick") && !hasAbility(character, "Pillar"))
          sliceMultiplier *= 2;
        if (enemy.getStat(enemy.primaryStat()) >= 25)
          sliceMultiplier *= 2;
        if (hasAbility(character, "Pillar")) {
          if (sliceDanger >= sliceMultiplier)
            continue;
          sliceDanger = 0;
        }
        sliceDanger += sliceMultiplier;
      }
    }
    return sliceDanger + otherDanger;
  }

  private ReadonlyAction[] forceFieldAction = new ReadonlyAction[3];
  private int goalX = 5;
  private int goalY = 5;

  @Override
  public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {

    /* Which character are we? */
    int characterNumber;
    if (hasAbility(character, "Focused"))
      characterNumber = 0;
    else if (hasAbility(character, "Immune"))
      characterNumber = 1;
    else if (hasAbility(character, "TrueSight"))
      characterNumber = 2;
    else
      throw new RuntimeException("Unrecognised character!");

    /* If we're at the goal square, pick a new one. */
    if (goalX == character.getLocation().getX() &&
        goalY == character.getLocation().getY()) {
      int i = getRandom().nextInt(5);
      goalX = i < 2 ? 1 : i > 2 ? 9 : 5;
      goalY = i == 2 ? 5 : (i % 2) == 1 ? 1 : 9;
    }

    /* If there are a lot of visible enemies, try to group up in a corner in order
       to prevent being surrounded. */
    if (visibleEnemies.size() > 3) {
      int xVotes = 0;
      int yVotes = 0;
      for (ReadonlyCharacter ally : team) {
        xVotes += ally.getLocation().getX() >= 5 ? 1 : -1;
        yVotes += ally.getLocation().getY() >= 5 ? 1 : -1;
      }
      goalX = xVotes > 0 ? 9 : 0;
      goalY = yVotes > 0 ? 9 : 0;
    }

    /* We need to know our Force Field cooldowns even between turns, so store the
       actions in a private field for later use (they aren't visible via the API) */
    for (ReadonlyAction action : actions) {
      if (action.getName().equals("ForceField"))
        forceFieldAction[characterNumber] = action;
    }

    /* If we know Force Field, ensure we always hang on to enough mana to cast it, and
       never allow our mana to dip low enough that it wouldn't regenerate in time. */
    double mpFloor = 0.0;
    if (forceFieldAction[characterNumber] != null) {
      double mpRegen = character.getStat(Stat.INT) / 10.0;
      if (hasAbility(character, "Focused"))
        mpRegen *= 2;
      mpFloor = forceFieldAction[characterNumber].getManaCost();
      mpFloor -= forceFieldAction[characterNumber].getRemainingCooldown() * mpRegen;
    }
    if (mpFloor > character.getMana())
      mpFloor = character.getMana();

    /* We use a priority rule for actions. */
    int bestPriority = -2;
    ReadonlyAction bestAction = null;
    for (ReadonlyAction action : actions) {
      int priority = 0;
      if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("ForceField"))
        priority = 20; /* top priority */
      else if (character.getMana() - action.getManaCost() < mpFloor) {
        continue; /* never spend mana if it'd block a force field */
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Quick") ||
                 lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Slice")) {
        int damagePotential =
          lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Quick") ? 50 : 25;
        /* We use these abilities with very high priority to /kill/ an enemy
           who's weak enough to die from the damage. If they wouldn't die,
           we're much more wary about attacking; we do it only if we have
           nothing better to do and it's safe. */
        ReadonlyCharacter chosenTarget = null;
        for (ReadonlyCharacter target : action.availableTargets()) {
          if (!isEnemy(target))
            continue;
          if (target.getHealth() <= damagePotential) {
            chosenTarget = target;
            priority = (damagePotential == 25 ? 19 : 18);
            break; /* can't do beter than this */
          }
          if (hasAbility(target, "Spikes") ||
              hasAbility(target, "Reflexive"))
            /*  (target.getLastAction() != null &&
                target.getLastAction().getName().equals("Ghost")) */
            continue; /* veto the target */
          priority = (damagePotential == 25 ? 3 : 4);
          chosenTarget = target;
        }
        if (chosenTarget == null)
          continue;
        action.setTarget(chosenTarget);
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Weave")) {
        priority = visibleEnemies.size() >= 3 ? 14 :
          visibleEnemies.size() >= 1 ? 6 : -1;
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Smile")) {
        /* If there's a stunned or poisoned enemy in view, we favour Smile
           as the idle action, rather than exploring, so that we don't
           move it out of view. Exception: if they're the only enemy;
           in that case, hunt them down. Another exception: if we're
           running into a corner. */
        for (EnemyCharacter enemy : visibleEnemies) {
          if (enemy.isStunned() || enemy.isPoisoned())
            if (visibleEnemies.size() > 1 && visibleEnemies.size() < 4)
              priority = 2;
        }
        /* otherwise we leave it as 0, and Smile only as a last resort */
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Knockout")) {
        /* Use this only on targets who have more than 50 HP. It doesn't
           matter where they are: if we can see them now, knocking them
           out will guarantee we can continue to see them. Of course, if
           they're already knocked out, don't use it (although this case
           should never come up). If there's only one enemy target in
           view, knocking it out has slightly higher priority, because
           we don't need to fear enemy attacks if all the enemies are
           knocked out.

           Mildly favour stunning poisoned enemies; this reduces the
           chance that they'll run out of sight and reset the poison. */
        ReadonlyCharacter chosenTarget = null;
        for (ReadonlyCharacter target : action.availableTargets())
          if ((target.getHealth() > 50 || target.isPoisoned()) &&
              !target.isStunned() && isEnemy(target)) {
            chosenTarget = target;
            if (target.isPoisoned())
              break;
          }
        if (chosenTarget == null)
          continue;
        action.setTarget(chosenTarget);
        priority = visibleEnemies.size() == 1 ? 17 : 15;
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Poison")) {
        /* Use this preferentially on stronger enemies, and preferentially
           on enemies who are more poisoned. We're willing to poison
           almost anyone, although weak enemies who aren't poisoned
           are faster to kill via slicing. The cutoff is at 49, not 50,
           so that in the case of evasive enemies who we can't hit any
           other way, we can wear them one at a time using poison. */
        ReadonlyCharacter chosenTarget = null;
        int chosenTargetPoisonLevel = -1;
        for (ReadonlyCharacter target : action.availableTargets()) {
          int poisonLevel = 0;

          if (!isEnemy(target))
            continue;
          if (target.isPoisoned())
            poisonLevel = target.getPoisonAmount() + 1;
          if (poisonLevel < chosenTargetPoisonLevel)
            continue;
          if (poisonLevel == 0 && target.getHealth() <= 49)
            continue; /* prefer stronger targets */
          if (poisonLevel == 0 && target.getHealth() == 50 &&
              chosenTarget != null)
            continue; /* we poison at 50, but not with other options */
          chosenTarget = target;
          chosenTargetPoisonLevel = poisonLevel;
          priority = 12;
        }
        if (chosenTarget == null)
          continue;
        action.setTarget(chosenTarget);
      } else if (action.movementAction()) {
        /* A move to a significantly safer square is worth 16.
           A move to a mildly safer square is worth 8.
           Otherwise, move to group, either with the enemy,
           the team, or the goal, at priority 1, if we
           safely can; that's our "idle" action. */
        int currentSquareDanger =
          getSquareDanger(character, character.getLocation());
        int bestSquareDanger = currentSquareDanger;
        int bestGroupiness = 0;
        Point2D bestLocation = null;
        priority = 1;
        for (Point2D location :
               action.availableLocations().toList().shuffleThis(getRandom())) {
          int danger = getSquareDanger(character, location);
          if (danger > bestSquareDanger)
            continue;
          else if (danger < bestSquareDanger) {
            priority = (currentSquareDanger - danger > 2)
              ? 16 : 8;
            bestSquareDanger = danger;
            bestLocation = location;
            bestGroupiness = 0; /* reset the tiebreak */
          }

          int cx = character.getLocation().getX();
          int xDelta = location.getX() - cx;
          int cy = character.getLocation().getY();
          int yDelta = location.getY() - cy;
          int groupiness = 0;
          /* Always hunt down a visible enemy when they're the only
             remaining enemy and doing so is safe. Otherwise, still
             favour hunting them down, but in that situation also
             consider factors like grouping and exploration. */
          for (Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keysView())
            if (xDelta * (enemyLocation.getX() - cx) > 0 ||
                yDelta * (enemyLocation.getY() - cy) > 0)
              groupiness += (visibleEnemies.size() == 1 ? 99 : 5);
          /* If there are 4 or more visible enemies, then grouping is
             vitally important (so as to not get surrounded).
             Otherwise, it's more minor. */
          for (ReadonlyCharacter ally : team)
            if (xDelta * (ally.getLocation().getX() - cx) > 0 ||
                yDelta * (ally.getLocation().getY() - cy) > 0)
              groupiness += (visibleEnemies.size() > 3 ? 99 : 3);
          /* When exploring, we bias towards random map locations,
             changing location when we reach them. This helps us beat
             enemies that hide in the corners. When there are a lot
             of visible enemies, this changes to a bias to hide in a
             corner. */
          if (xDelta * (goalX - cx) > 0 ||
              yDelta * (goalY - cy) > 0)
            groupiness += (visibleEnemies.size() > 3 ? 99 : 4);
          if (groupiness >= bestGroupiness) {
            bestLocation = location;
            bestGroupiness = groupiness;
            /* leave priority, safety untouched */
          }
        }
        if (bestLocation == null)
          continue;
        action.setLocation(bestLocation);
      } else
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown action" + action.getName());

      if (priority > bestPriority) {
        bestPriority = priority;
        bestAction = action;
      }
    }
    if (bestAction == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("no action?");

    return bestAction;
  }
}
```

Comment: very effective :) stunning is looking like an effective strategy!

Comment: Your character with ForceField cannot be defeated by my Noobs, even though it has only 50 health!

Comment: Fixed a bug that @Sleafar pointed out.

Comment: i think you are having a few too many skillpoints on your falconer and trollbone

Comment: Fixed too. It was just a typo in the description, the code was correct.

Answer (score 7):

## TheWalkingDead

Zombies, everyone knows them. They stay in a group doing nothing until someone shows up. They are hard to kill, and no matter how many you kill there are always more. And they usually appear out of nowhere just behind your back.

- 1 x **Zombie #1** (the strongest, and therefore the alpha zombie)

  - **STR:** 25; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 15
  - **Clone**, **Resurrect**, **Strong**
- 2 x **Zombie #2** (no one wanted to be Zombie #3 in the closing credits, therefore both got the same number)

  - **STR:** 15; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 15
  - **Clone**, **Resurrect**, **Absorb**

*You may reuse single characters from here in your team, as long as you add at least one more character which is not present here.*

```java
TheWalkingDead.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Absorb;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.Resurrect;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class TheWalkingDead extends SleafarPlayer {
    private CharacterTemplate zombie1Template() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 10, new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new Resurrect(), new Strong());
    }

    private CharacterTemplate zombie2Template() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(10, 0, 10, new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new Resurrect(), new Absorb());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        return Arrays.asList(zombie1Template(), zombie2Template(), zombie2Template());
    }

    private class Zombie extends Character {
        private int resurrectCountdown = 0;
        private double oldHealth;

        protected Zombie(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
            this.oldHealth = getHealth();
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            if (getHealth() > oldHealth + getHealthRegen() + 0.1) {
                resurrectCountdown = 40;
            }
            if (resurrectCountdown > 0) {
                --resurrectCountdown;
            }
            oldHealth = getHealth();

            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            if (resurrectCountdown > 0) {
                if (step != null && isInEnemySliceRange() && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                    return step;
                }
                if (clone != null && !getSliceLocations().isEmpty() && setClosestLocation(clone, getSliceLocations())) {
                    return clone;
                }
                if (clone != null && setCloneLocation(clone, 1)) {
                    return clone;
                }
                if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                    return slice;
                }
                if (step != null && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                    return step;
                }
            } else {
                if (clone != null && !getSliceLocations().isEmpty() && setClosestLocation(clone, getSliceLocations())) {
                    return clone;
                }
                if (clone != null && setCloneLocation(clone, 1)) {
                    return clone;
                }
                if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                    return slice;
                }
                if (step != null && !getSliceLocations().isEmpty() && setClosestLocation(step, getSliceLocations())) {
                    return step;
                }
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
        return new Zombie(delegate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot get your bots to work... the Sleafar base class imports a fellowship.characters.CharacterInterface that does not seem to be in the latest master branch...

Comment: @Moogie Nathan [fixed the problem](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/commit/d003f11d1df619160b202d5eb9b3f7cee8050c30).

Answer (score 6):

### Bear Cavalry

Uses **Absorb**, **Clone** and **Bear**; stats are **(+9, +0, +11)**.

On the first turn, everyone creates a clone of themselves, so that the team has 6 characters on the field.
Then they charge the enemy, spamming bears whenever they can, and weakening their foes with stat-absorbing attacks.

The code is a mess, but it seems to work.
I copied parts of it from Template Player.

*You can use the characters of this team in any way you like.*

```java
BearCavalry.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Absorb;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.actions.other.Bear;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.Player;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class BearCavalry extends Player{
    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(9, 0, 11,
                        new Absorb(),
                        new ActionAbility(Clone::new),
                        new ActionAbility(Bear::new)));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
    for(ReadonlyAction action: actions){
        if (action.getName().equals("Clone") && action.isAvailable()){
        action.setLocation(toTeam(action.availableLocations(), character));
        return action;
        }
    }
    for(ReadonlyAction action: actions){
        if (action.getName().equals("Bear") && action.isAvailable()){
        action.setLocation(toEnemy(action.availableLocations(), character));
        return action;
        }
    }
    for(ReadonlyAction action: actions){
        if (action.getName().equals("Slice") && action.isAvailable()){
        action.setTarget(action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
        return action;
        }
    }
    for(ReadonlyAction action: actions){
        if (action.getName().equals("Step") && action.isAvailable()){
        action.setLocation(toEnemy(action.availableLocations(), character));
        return action;
        }
    }
    for(ReadonlyAction action: actions){
        if (action.getName().equals("Smile")){
        return action;
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

    private Point2D toTeam(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (team.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                        p1.diagonalDistance(character.getLocation())
                        );
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                    p1.diagonalDistance(team.collect(ReadonlyCharacter::getLocation).minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
                    );
    }

    private Point2D toEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return toTeam(availableLocations, character);
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                    p1.diagonalDistance(visibleEnemies.keyValuesView().minBy(p -> p.getTwo().getHealth()).getOne())
                    );
    }
}
```

Comment: your bears are an effective strategy against my coward sniper :) too many targets for my bot to get into a stand-off position to start zapping! well done

Answer (score 6):

## Vampire

I'm new to this and I'm not sure I know what I'm doing, but I thought it seemed interesting, so here is my attempt.

The vampires will search for enemies and target the weakest, draining the life from them, while growing stronger and regaining their own health, ready to move on to their next victim. Should they be significantly injured, they will attempt to move away until their natural regeneration restores them to fighting condition.

Using **Absorb**, **Feast**, **Regenerate**, **Strong** with everything in **STR**

```java
Vampire.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Absorb;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Feast;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Regenerate;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.Player;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Vampire extends Player{
    private final double CRITICAL_HEALTH = 5;
    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(30, 0, 0,
                    new Absorb(),
                    new Feast(),
                    new Regenerate(),
                    new Strong()));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        int minPriority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ReadonlyAction chosen = null;
        for (ReadonlyAction action: actions){
            int priority = getPriorityFor(action, character);
            if (priority < minPriority){
                chosen = action;
                minPriority = priority;
            }
        }
        if (chosen == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }
        if (chosen.needsLocation()){
            chosen.setLocation(chooseLocationFor(chosen, character));
        } else if (chosen.needsTarget()){
            chosen.setTarget(chooseTargetFor(chosen));
        }
        return chosen;
    }

    private Point2D chooseLocationFor(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (action.movementAction()){
            if (character.getHealth() <= CRITICAL_HEALTH){
                return fromEnemy(action.availableLocations());
            } else {
                return toEnemy(action.availableLocations());
            }
        }
        return toTeam(action.availableLocations());
    }

    private Point2D toEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private Point2D fromEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.maxBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private Point2D toTeam(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (team.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.iterator().next();
        }
        return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(team.collect(ReadonlyCharacter::getLocation).minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private ReadonlyCharacter chooseTargetFor(ReadonlyAction action){
        return action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth);
    }

    private int getPriorityFor(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character){
        if (action.getName().equals("Smile")){
            return 1000;
        }
        if (action.movementAction()){
            if (character.getHealth() <= CRITICAL_HEALTH){
                return 0;
            }
            return 999;
        }
        if (action.needsTarget()) {
            return ((int) action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth).getHealth());
        }
        return 998;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the use of all passive actions! Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

## Spiky

Spiky is, as his names implies, not to be attacked blindly. He's tanky, can regenerate a whole lot of HP, and hits like a truck. He will hover in the center of the map, waiting for someone to come close.

Using **Strong** (STR +10) x2, **Regenerate**, **Spikes** and going full STR (+40, 0, 0).

```java
Spiky.java

import fellowship.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;

import fellowship.abilities.defensive.Spikes;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Regenerate;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class Spiky extends Player {

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(40, 0, 0,
                    new Strong(),
                    new Strong(),
                    new Regenerate(),
                    new Spikes()));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {

        ReadonlyAction chosen = null;
        Boolean canSlice = false;
        for (ReadonlyAction action: actions) {
            if (action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                canSlice = true;
            }
        }

        for (ReadonlyAction action: actions) {
             if (action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                 chosen = action;
                 chosen.setTarget(action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
             }
             if (!canSlice && action.getName().equals("Step")){
                 int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 6 + 1);
                 int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 6 + 1);
                 chosen = action;
                 Point2D destination = null;
                 if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
                     destination = action.availableLocations().minBy(p1 -> p1.cartesianDistance(new Point2D(x, y)));
                 } else {
                     destination = action.availableLocations().minBy(p1 -> p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance)));
                 }
                 chosen.setLocation(destination);
             }
        }
        if (chosen == null){
            for (ReadonlyAction action: actions){
                if (action.getName().equals("Smile")){
                    chosen = action;
                }
            }
        }

        return chosen;
    }

}
```

Comment: > Your submission should not have a package declaration. Your submission should be contained in the first multi-line code block, and the first line must have the file name.

Comment: I just stated what was said in the post.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Guess that's the only thing I did right. Thanks.

Comment: Nice bot! Spiky defeated the best of my bots.

Comment: Can you change `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` to `getRandom()`?  It allows for games to be deterministic.

Comment: Spiky has a little bug. When neither "slice" nor "step" is possible he returns "null" as action which crashes the controller.

Comment: I've fixed the code for the above two issues.

Answer (score 5):

## Sorcerer

Clones himself to deal as much instant damage to all enemies as possible with *Weave* (it was lightning previously, but *Weave* does more damage and has a lower mana cost.

```java
Sorcerer.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.Player;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.TrueSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Slice;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Weave;
import fellowship.actions.mobility.Step;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.actions.other.Smile;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;

public class Sorcerer extends Player {

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                    new ActionAbility(Clone::new),
                    new TrueSight(),
                    new ActionAbility(Weave::new)));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        ReadonlyAction chosen = getBestAction(actions, character);
        if (chosen == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }
        if (chosen.needsLocation()){
            chosen.setLocation(toEnemy(chosen.availableLocations()));
        } else if (chosen.needsTarget()){
            chosen.setTarget(chooseTargetFor(chosen));
        }
        return chosen;
    }

    private Point2D toEnemy(MutableSet<Point2D> availableLocations){
        if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()){
            return availableLocations.minBy(p1 ->
                    p1.cartesianDistance(team.minBy(x -> p1.cartesianDistance(x.getLocation())).getLocation())
            );
        }

        return availableLocations.maxBy(p1 ->
                p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().maxBy(p1::cartesianDistance))
        );
    }

    private ReadonlyCharacter chooseTargetFor(ReadonlyAction action){
        return action.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth);
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getBestAction(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        Map<Class<?>, ReadonlyAction> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (ReadonlyAction action : actions) {
            actionMap.put(action.actionClass(), action);
        }

        ReadonlyAction clone = actionMap.get(Clone.class);
        if (clone != null && clone.isAvailable() && !clone.availableLocations().isEmpty()) {
            return clone;
        }

        ReadonlyAction weave = actionMap.get(Weave.class);
        if (weave != null && weave.isAvailable() && (clone == null || clone.getRemainingCooldown() > 0)) {
            return weave;
        }

        ReadonlyAction slice = actionMap.get(Slice.class);
        if (slice != null && slice.isAvailable() && !slice.availableLocations().isEmpty() && !character.isInvisible()) {
            return slice;
        }

        ReadonlyAction step = actionMap.get(Step.class);
        if (step != null && step.isAvailable()) {
            return step;
        }

        return actionMap.get(Smile.class);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Cloning seems to be a popular choice for bots... I should use your bot as inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

## LongSword

Uses **Ranged** (Adds 1 to the range of Slice), **Flexible** (Can Slice in any of the 8 directions), **Quick** (Slice twice, Mana: 3, Cooldown: 0), **Strong** (You gain 10 more attribute points)

#### STATS

The starting 5 points is the base

- **STR:** 5 + 20 + 10
- **AGI:** 5 + 0
- **INT:** 5 + 0

---

First of all, I really enjoyed making this bot, and I really like this KotH (this is my first submission to a KotH challenge!). (I might post more bots)

#### The Bot

This bot relies on Attack abilities to overpower its opponents. As far as I tested, this bot is really good against bots with relatively low health. Also, it has a large attack range, and can easily target most (or half) enemies in its sight.

To compare this bot with a NetHack role, I would say it resembles closely to the [Valkyrie](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Valkyrie) due to the concept of the "LongSword" and the average health.

**NAME**

This bot has a slightly longer range than normal bots and it can attack in any direction. This reminded me most of the Long Sword in NetHack, so I named my bot as such.

**BEHAVIOUR**

If the character cannot see an enemy character, then it will go the the opposite side of the field (the enemy's spawn area/enemy's "base") to find enemy characters. If it finds enemies, then it will attack them with Quick, Slice (in decreasing priority). If it can't target enemies, then the bot will go towards the enemy characters to destroy them.

If the character cannot see an enemy character **and** has low health, then it will retreat towards "base"/spawn area.

> Note: The bot will never retreat in the middle of battle. This bot will never Smile.

I used the following [regex](http://www.regexr.com/3emv2) on regexr.com to convert my Java code into a formatted code block.

The code below is commented so it should be easy to understand. If you have any questions or clarifications on how it works, feel free to ping me in the [Battle of the Fellowships chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48475/battle-of-the-fellowships)!

> Edit: I fixed a minor mistake in my program to adapt the bot's movement (forwards|backwards) depending on where it started. I forgot to do this, so I edited it in now.

```java
LongSword.java

import fellowship.*;
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Flexible;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Ranged;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class LongSword/*Closest NetHack Role: Valkyrie*/ extends Player{

    //debugging
    private boolean debug = false;
    private void println(String text) {
        if(debug)
            System.out.println(text);
    }

    //variables use to hold the start Y coordinate of the bot
    private boolean started = false;
    private int startY = 5;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(30, 0, 0,
                    new Ranged(), //Adds 1 to the range of Slice
                    new Flexible(), //Can Slice in any of the 8 directions
                    new ActionAbility(Quick::new), //Slice twice, Mana: 3, Cooldown: 0
                    new Strong())); //You gain 10 attribute points
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(!started) {
            startY = character.getLocation().getY(); //giving startY the value of the bot's starting y-value
            started = true; //do this only once, that's why there is the if statement
        }

        ReadonlyAction current = null;

        //choosing action depending on priority
        int priority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ReadonlyAction action:actions) {
            int priorityLocal = getPriority(action, character);
            if(priorityLocal < priority) {
                current = action;
                priority = priorityLocal;
            }
        }

        if (current == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }

        println(current.getName());

        if(current.needsLocation()) {
            if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
                if (character.getHealth() < 100) {
                    //if has low health, go backwards towards "base"
                    //println("lowHealth");
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "backward"));
                } else {
                    //else go forwards to enemy's "base"
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "forward"));
                }
            }else{
                //go towards closest enemy
                current.setLocation(current.availableLocations().minBy(p1->p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))));
            }
        }
        if(current.needsTarget()) {
            //get closest target
            current.setTarget(current.availableTargets().minBy(p1 -> 0));
        }

        return current;
    }

    //move backwards or forwards
    private Point2D move(ReadonlyAction readonlyAction, ReadonlyCharacter character, String direction) {
        Point2D location = null;

        //move direction depending on Y coordinate of point
        for(Point2D point2D:readonlyAction.availableLocations()) {
            switch (direction) {
                case "forward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot started at top
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
                case "backward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot started at top
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

        //if no available locations, just choose the first available location
        if(location == null) {
            location = readonlyAction.availableLocations().iterator().next();
        }

        println(location.getY()+","+character.getLocation().getY());

        return location;
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
            //if there are no visible enemies, Step. In the choose function, this becomes move forward or backward depending on health
            if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 100;
            }
        }else {
            /*
             * PRIORITIES:
             *  1. Quick (Slice twice)
             *  2. Slice
             *  3. Step (when enemy is not in range --> move towards enemy)
             */
            if (action.getName().equals("Quick")) {
                return 1;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                return 10;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 50;
            }
        }
        //Kids, don't Smile, instead Step or Slice
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: puts my cowards to shame. good work

Answer (score 4):

## Derailer

Had to delete it *twice* since I had a bunch of logic errors. :P

This one can certainly derail your plans. ;)

The team:

- 1 character with **Critical**, **Buff**, **Strong**, and **Quick** to quickly take out enemies while being very difficult to defeat. **+25 STR, +2 AGI, +3 INT**
- 1 character with **Clever**, **Clever**, **Restore**, and **Zap**. Stays behind as support and restores the health of any teammates that are running low on HP, and can attack and defend itself necessary. **+14 STR, +3 AGI, +3 INT**
- 1 character with **TrueSight**, **Spikes**, **Evasive**, and **Weave**. Not so easy to hit, and if you do, or if you get too close, it will see you and strike. **+13 STR, +3 AGI, +4 INT**

```java
Derailer.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.Player;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.ReadonlyAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Critical;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.Evasive;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.Spikes;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Buff;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Clever;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.TrueSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Weave;
import fellowship.actions.damage.Zap;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.Restore;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Derailer extends Player {
    private static final double CRITICAL_HEALTH_PCT = .175;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new CharacterTemplate(14, 3, 3,
                                       new Clever(),
                                       new Clever(),
                                       new ActionAbility(Restore::new),
                                       new ActionAbility(Zap::new)));

        list.add(new CharacterTemplate(25, 2, 3,
                                       new Critical(),
                                       new Buff(),
                                       new ActionAbility(Quick::new),
                                       new Strong()));

        list.add(new CharacterTemplate(13, 3, 4,
                                       new TrueSight(),
                                       new Spikes(),
                                       new Evasive(),
                                       new ActionAbility(Weave::new)));
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        List<ReadonlyAbility> abilities = character.getAbilities();
        ReadonlyAction action = null;

        for (ReadonlyAbility a : abilities) {
            String s = a.name();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (i == -1)
                continue;
            s = s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            if (s.equals("Clever")) {
                action = getActionForChar1(character, actions);
                break;
            }
            else if (s.equals("Buff")) {
                action = getActionForChar2(character, actions);
                break;
            }
            else if (s.equals("Evasive")) {
                action = getActionForChar3(character, actions);
                break;
            }
        }

        return action;
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getActionForChar1(ReadonlyCharacter character, Set<ReadonlyAction> actions) {
        int members = (int) team.stream().filter(c -> !c.isDead()).count();

        List<ReadonlyAction> list = actions.stream()
                                           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::getPriority))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (ReadonlyAction a : list) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.equals("Restore")) {
                for (ReadonlyCharacter teammate : team) {
                    if (teammate.getHealth() / teammate.getMaxHealth() < CRITICAL_HEALTH_PCT * (4 - members))
                        return a;
                }
            }
            else if (name.equals("Zap") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets()
                             .stream()
                             .reduce(
                                 BinaryOperator.minBy(
                                     Comparator.<ReadonlyCharacter>comparingDouble(e -> e.getHealth())
                                 )
                             )
                             .get()
                );
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Slice") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().iterator().next());
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Smile"))
                return a;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No available actions");
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getActionForChar2(ReadonlyCharacter character, Set<ReadonlyAction> actions) {
        List<ReadonlyAction> list = actions.stream()
                                           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::getPriority))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (ReadonlyAction a : list) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.equals("Quick") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Slice") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Step") && !a.availableLocations().isEmpty()) {
                Point2D e = getClosestEnemyPoint(character);
                if (e == null) {
                    Point2D p = character.getLocation();
                    if (p.getY() > 5) {
                        a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                       .stream()
                                       .filter(x -> x.getY() < p.getY())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .orElse(a.availableLocations().iterator().next()));
                    }
                    else if (p.getY() < 4) {
                        a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                       .stream()
                                       .filter(x -> x.getY() > p.getY())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .orElse(a.availableLocations().iterator().next()));
                    }
                    else
                        a.setLocation(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations())));
                }
                else {
                    int currentDistance = character.getLocation().cartesianDistance(e);
                    a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(x -> x.cartesianDistance(e) < currentDistance)
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations()))));
                }
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Smile"))
                return a;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No available actions");
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getActionForChar3(ReadonlyCharacter character, Set<ReadonlyAction> actions) {
        List<ReadonlyAction> list = actions.stream()
                                           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::getPriority))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (ReadonlyAction a : list) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.equals("Weave") && visibleEnemies.keySet().size() > 1)
                return a;
            else if (name.equals("Slice") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().iterator().next());
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Smile"))
                return a;
            else if (name.equals("Step")) {
                Point2D p = character.getLocation();
                if (!visibleEnemies.keySet().isEmpty()) {
                    Point2D e = getClosestEnemyPoint(character);
                    int currentDistance = character.getLocation().cartesianDistance(e);
                    a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(x -> x.cartesianDistance(e) < currentDistance)
                                   .findAny()
                                   .orElse(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations()))));
                }
                else if (p.getY() > 5) {
                    a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(x -> x.getY() < p.getY())
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations()))));
                }
                else if (p.getY() < 4) {
                    a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(x -> x.getY() > p.getY())
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations()))));
                }
                else
                    a.setLocation(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations())));
                return a;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No available actions");
    }

    private Point2D getClosestEnemyPoint(ReadonlyCharacter c) {
        return visibleEnemies.keySet()
                             .stream()
                             .reduce(
                                 BinaryOperator.minBy(
                                     Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.cartesianDistance(c.getLocation()))
                                 )
                             )
                             .orElse(null);
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action) {
        switch (action.getName()) {
            case "Quick":
            case "Restore":
            case "Weave":
                return 1;
            case "Zap": return 2;
            case "Slice": return 3;
            case "Step": return 4;
            case "Smile": return 5;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(action));
    }

    private Point2D randomLocation(List<Point2D> l) {
        return l.get((int) (Math.random() * l.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting team dynamics! makes me want to try for some more advanced team action :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to incorporate synergy within the team, but the third character seems a little out of place. Perhaps I'll improve upon this strategy in a future bot.

Comment: Interestingly, replacing the third character with a copy of the first resulted in much better results.

Answer (score 4):

## SniperSquad

A sniper squad consists of:

- 1 **Spotter** (equipped with the best spotting gear available, allowing an overview of almost the whole map)

  - **STR:** 25; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 5
  - **Far sight**, **Far sight**, **Far sight**, **Far sight**
- 2 **Shooters** (equipped with the newest multi target sniper rifles, the only drawback is the slow fire rate)

  - **STR:** 25; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 5
  - **Weave**, **Critical**, **Critical**, **Critical**

*You may reuse single characters from here in your team, as long as you add at least one more character which is not present here.*

```java
SniperSquad.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Critical;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.FarSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Weave;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class SniperSquad extends SleafarPlayer {
    private static CharacterTemplate spotterTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                new FarSight(), new FarSight(), new FarSight(), new FarSight());
    }

    private static CharacterTemplate shooterTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                new ActionAbility(Weave::new), new Critical(), new Critical(), new Critical());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        return Arrays.asList(shooterTemplate(), spotterTemplate(), shooterTemplate());
    }

    private class Spotter extends Character {
        protected Spotter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 100.0)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && isInEnemyStepSightRange() && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && setExploreLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    private class Shooter extends Character {
        protected Shooter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction weave = getAction(Weave.class);
            if (weave != null && !visibleEnemies.isEmpty() &&
                    visibleEnemies.collectDouble(e -> calcSliceRetaliationDamage(e)).sum() < getHealth()) {
                return weave;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 100.0)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
        if (hasAbility(delegate, FarSight.class)) {
            return new Spotter(delegate);
        } else if (hasAbility(delegate, Weave.class)) {
            return new Shooter(delegate);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hehe, your snipers out snipe my coward snipers :) good work

Answer (score 3):

## Werewolves

I am not the greatest at writing AI *choice selection*, especially for a ruleset as complex as this one. Combined with low ability to view a gamestate and observe the actors making decisions (and with the outcomes slightly different between runs, there's little ability to calculate a success margin of slight changes in order to improve the AI logic), but I was able to make a superior ability/attribute selection that dominated the existing bot set.

Uses **Ranged**, **Swipe**, **Strong**, and **Werewolf** and otherwise uses the same AI logic as [LongSword](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100456/47990), although slightly altered.

Tough to choose the most ideal values, as even no changes can sometimes result in dropping from "best" to "worst."  The health-retreat-threshold is 50 here, but it seems that any value between 10 and 70 results in similar results (no other bots that provide a high enough challenge to distinguish the precise peak of performance).

```java
PlayerWerewolf.java

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;

import fellowship.Player;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Ranged;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Swipe;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.stats.Werewolf;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.characters.EnemyCharacter;

public class PlayerWerewolf extends Player {
    //variables use to hold the start Y coordinate of the bot
    private boolean started = false;
    private int startY = 5;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(30, 0, 0,
                    new Ranged(), //Adds 1 to the range of Slice
                    new Swipe(), //Deal increasing damage
                    new ActionAbility(Werewolf::new), //Turn into a werewolf for 5 turns
                    new Strong())); //You gain 10 attribute points
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(!started) {
            startY = character.getLocation().getY(); //giving startY the value of the bot's starting y-value
            started = true; //do this only once, that's why there is the if statement
        }

        ReadonlyAction current = null;

        //choosing action depending on priority
        int priority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ReadonlyAction action:actions) {
            int priorityLocal = getPriority(action, character);
            if(priorityLocal < priority) {
                current = action;
                priority = priorityLocal;
            }
        }

        if (current == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }

        if(current.needsLocation()) {
            if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
                if (character.getHealth() < 50) {
                    //if has low health, go backwards towards "base"
                    //println("lowHealth");
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "backward"));
                } else {
                    //else go forwards to enemy's "base"
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "forward"));
                }
            }else{
                //go towards closest enemy
                current.setLocation(current.availableLocations().minBy(p1->p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))));
            }
        }
        if(current.needsTarget()) {
            //get closest target
            current.setTarget(current.availableTargets().minBy(p1 -> 0));
        }

        return current;
    }

    //move backwards or forwards
    private Point2D move(ReadonlyAction readonlyAction, ReadonlyCharacter character, String direction) {
        Point2D location = null;

        //move direction depending on Y coordinate of point
        for(Point2D point2D:readonlyAction.availableLocations()) {
            switch (direction) {
            case "forward":
                if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                    if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                        location = point2D;
                }else{ //bot started at top
                    if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                        location = point2D;
                }
                break;
            case "backward":
                if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                    if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                        location = point2D;
                }else{ //bot started at top
                    if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                        location = point2D;
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        //if no available locations, just choose the first available location
        if(location == null) {
            location = readonlyAction.availableLocations().iterator().next();
        }

        return location;
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
            //if there are no visible enemies, Step. In the choose function, this becomes move forward or backward depending on health
            if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 100;
            }
        }else {
            /*
             * PRIORITIES:
             *  1. If near an enemy, and not a werewolf, turn into a werewolf
             *  2. Slice
             *  3. Step (when enemy is not in range --> move towards enemy)
             */
            if (action.getName().equals("Werewolf") && action.isAvailable()) {
                EnemyWrapper wrap = getNearestEnemy(character);
                //don't turn into a werewolf unless we're close to an enemy
                if(wrap.location.diagonalDistance(character.getLocation()) < 3) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                return 10;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 50;
            }
        }
        //Kids, don't Smile, instead Step or Slice
        return 1000;
    }

    private EnemyWrapper getNearestEnemy(ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        double closestEnemyDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Point2D closestEnemy = null;
        for ( Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keySet()) {
            double visionDistanceDiff = character.getLocation().diagonalDistance(enemyLocation);
            if (visionDistanceDiff< closestEnemyDistance)
            {
                closestEnemyDistance = visionDistanceDiff;
                closestEnemy = enemyLocation;
            }
        }
        return new EnemyWrapper(visibleEnemies.get(closestEnemy), closestEnemy);
    }
    private static class EnemyWrapper {
        public final EnemyCharacter enemy;
        public final Point2D location;
        
        EnemyWrapper(EnemyCharacter e, Point2D l) {
            enemy = e;
            location = l;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There were a couple of issues (a package declaration, as well as not putting the filename on the first line), and I fixed them.  That said, I can't get the static class to get past my compiler...looking into it.

Comment: I figured it out:  you were missing an import: `import fellowship.characters.EnemyCharacter;`

Comment: @NathanMerrill I tried to combine the secondary class into an internal class outside Eclipse, that's probably what that was.

Comment: Nice! You used my own movement functions from LongSword!

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yep, I was having trouble writing the "ai" portion of things so I snagged one that was simplistic just to have a starting point and it worked really well.  I've been trying to fiddle with them to see if I can make it do any better, as they'll just keep marching forward if they can't see anyone, even if their opponent is behind them, but hasn't made much difference.  Mostly because neither the wolves nor the Long Swordsmen have anyway of countering invisibility.

Answer (score 2):

## Railbender

This bot is simply a version of **Derailer** that has had its third character replaced with a copy of the first. It produces much better results compared to Derailer.

While creating Derailer, I wanted to give each character abilities that would synergize well with each other. Having one character with high HP and attack power and another character with the Restore action worked together nicely. However, it didn't seem like the third character fit in very well. That probably was the main reason Derailer didn't produce good results. So I figured that having a third character that can work well with and benefit from the others would be a better idea.

```java
Railbender.java

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.Player;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.ReadonlyAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Critical;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Buff;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Clever;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.actions.damage.Zap;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.Restore;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Railbender extends Player {
    private static final double CRITICAL_HEALTH_PCT = .175;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new CharacterTemplate(14, 3, 3,
                                       new Clever(),
                                       new Clever(),
                                       new ActionAbility(Restore::new),
                                       new ActionAbility(Zap::new)));

        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            list.add(new CharacterTemplate(25, 2, 3,
                                           new Critical(),
                                           new Buff(),
                                           new ActionAbility(Quick::new),
                                           new Strong()));
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        List<ReadonlyAbility> abilities = character.getAbilities();
        ReadonlyAction action = null;

        for (ReadonlyAbility a : abilities) {
            String s = a.name();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (i == -1)
                continue;
            s = s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            if (s.equals("Clever")) {
                action = getActionForChar1(character, actions);
                break;
            }
            else if (s.equals("Buff")) {
                action = getActionForChar2(character, actions);
                break;
            }
        }

        return action;
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getActionForChar1(ReadonlyCharacter character, Set<ReadonlyAction> actions) {
        int members = (int) team.stream().filter(c -> !c.isDead()).count();

        List<ReadonlyAction> list = actions.stream()
                                           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::getPriority))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Point2D closestEnemy = getClosestEnemyPoint(character);

        for (ReadonlyAction a : list) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.equals("Restore")) {
                for (ReadonlyCharacter teammate : team) {
                    if (teammate.getHealth() / teammate.getMaxHealth() < CRITICAL_HEALTH_PCT * (4 - members))
                        return a;
                }
            }
            else if (name.equals("Zap") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty() && closestEnemy != null &&
                     character.getLocation().cartesianDistance(closestEnemy) <= 4) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets()
                             .stream()
                             .reduce(
                                 BinaryOperator.minBy(
                                     Comparator.<ReadonlyCharacter>comparingDouble(e -> e.getHealth())
                                 )
                             )
                             .get()
                );
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Slice") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().iterator().next());
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Smile"))
                return a;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No available actions");
    }

    private ReadonlyAction getActionForChar2(ReadonlyCharacter character, Set<ReadonlyAction> actions) {
        List<ReadonlyAction> list = actions.stream()
                                           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::getPriority))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (ReadonlyAction a : list) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.equals("Quick") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Slice") && !a.availableTargets().isEmpty()) {
                a.setTarget(a.availableTargets().minBy(ReadonlyCharacter::getHealth));
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Step") && !a.availableLocations().isEmpty()) {
                Point2D e = getClosestEnemyPoint(character);
                if (e == null) {
                    Point2D p = character.getLocation();
                    if (p.getY() > 5) {
                        a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                       .stream()
                                       .filter(x -> x.getY() < p.getY())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .orElse(a.availableLocations().iterator().next()));
                    }
                    else if (p.getY() < 4) {
                        a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                       .stream()
                                       .filter(x -> x.getY() > p.getY())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .orElse(a.availableLocations().iterator().next()));
                    }
                    else
                        a.setLocation(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations())));
                }
                else {
                    int currentDistance = character.getLocation().cartesianDistance(e);
                    a.setLocation(a.availableLocations()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(x -> x.cartesianDistance(e) < currentDistance)
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(randomLocation(new ArrayList<>(a.availableLocations()))));
                }
                return a;
            }
            else if (name.equals("Smile"))
                return a;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No available actions");
    }

    private Point2D getClosestEnemyPoint(ReadonlyCharacter c) {
        return visibleEnemies.keySet()
                             .stream()
                             .reduce(
                                 BinaryOperator.minBy(
                                     Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.cartesianDistance(c.getLocation()))
                                 )
                             )
                             .orElse(null);
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action) {
        switch (action.getName()) {
            case "Quick":
            case "Restore":
                return 1;
            case "Zap": return 2;
            case "Slice": return 3;
            case "Step": return 4;
            case "Smile": return 5;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(action));
    }

    private Point2D randomLocation(List<Point2D> l) {
        return l.get((int) (Math.random() * l.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! This is way tougher than Derailer

Answer (score 2):

## `Noob/*Destroyer*/`

Uses **Strong** * 2, **Regenerate**, and **Stun** (Stuns target for the next 300 ticks)

#### STATS

- **STR**: 5 + 40
- **AGI**: 5 + 0
- **INT**: 5 + 0

---

#### AI

Most of Noob's code is taken from my LongSword.

#### Strategy

When the character first sees an enemy character, priority is giving to Stunning the enemy first, and then Slicing the enemy while they are stunned. And with its high health and regeneration, Noob should be able to survive until it is able to use Stun again.

```java
Noob.java
import fellowship.*;
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.Stat;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Regenerate;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.Shield;
import fellowship.actions.statuses.Silence;
import fellowship.actions.statuses.Stun;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.Player;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.MutableSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Noob/*Destroyer*/ extends Player {

    private boolean debug = false;
    private void println(String text) {
        if(debug)
            System.out.println(text);
    }

    private boolean started = false;
    private int startY = 5;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(40, 0, 0,
                    new Regenerate(),
                    new ActionAbility(Stun::new),
                    new Strong(),
                    new Strong()));
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(!started) {
            startY = character.getLocation().getY();
            started = true;
        }

        ReadonlyAction readonlyAction = null;

        //get priority of action
        int priority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(ReadonlyAction action:actions) {
            int priorityLocal = getPriority(action, character);
            if(priorityLocal < priority) {
                readonlyAction = action;
                priority = priorityLocal;
            }
        }

        if (readonlyAction == null){
            println("NULL!");
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }

        //movement
        if(readonlyAction.needsLocation()) {
            if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
                if (character.getHealth() < 100) {
                    readonlyAction.setLocation(move(readonlyAction, character, "backward"));
                } else {
                    readonlyAction.setLocation(move(readonlyAction, character, "forward")); //enemy base is "forward"
                }
            }else{
                readonlyAction.setLocation(readonlyAction.availableLocations().minBy(p1->p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))));
            }
        }

        if(readonlyAction.needsTarget()) {
            readonlyAction.setTarget(readonlyAction.availableTargets().minBy(p1 -> 0));
        }

        return readonlyAction;
    }

    private Point2D move(ReadonlyAction readonlyAction, ReadonlyCharacter character, String direction) {
        Point2D location = null;

        for(Point2D point2D:readonlyAction.availableLocations()) {
            switch (direction) {
                case "forward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot starts at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot starts at top
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
                case "backward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot starts at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot starts at top
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

        if(location == null) {
            location = readonlyAction.availableLocations().iterator().next();
        }
        return location;
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
            if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 100;
            }
        }else {
            if (action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                return 10;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 50;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Stun") && !action.availableTargets().minBy(p1->0).isStunned()) {
                //if target is not stunned, stun 'em
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Living Wall

A wall of living wood that can walk along the battlefield, landing strong hits on any enemy that comes by, and draining the sap out of them to bolster its maximum health. Its root system can detect vibrations, allowing it to lash out even at invisible enemies. It consists of:

- 2 **Branches**: **STR** 35, **AGI** 5, **INT** 5, **Strong**, **Buff**, **Buff**, **Absorb**
- 1 **Root** : **STR** 25, **AGI**, 5, **INT**, 5, **True Sight**, **Buff**, **Buff**, **Absorb**

The AI is incredibly simple: find the enemy nearest to the team, then the entire wall focuses on that single enemy. There are only minor complications: if no enemies are in sight, walk towards random corners of and/or the centre of the map (thus eventually hunting down enemies who are hiding); if an enemy is within reach, attack it even if it isn't the enemy we're targeting (but prefer to focus on the enemy we're targeting, and even more so enemies we can OHKO).

The team does incredibly well; in simulations, the only team (that exists at the time of writing) that can beat it is RogueSquad, and even then not always (sometimes even RogueSquad dies to the might of the wall). Invulnerables sometimes manages to scrape a draw.

<s>The basic reason for the team's success is due to the combo of Buff×2 and Absorb; this means that every time we hit a STR-primary enemy, we're effectively gaining 40 HP in the short term (only 10 HP in the long term due to the increased regeneration from the stolen STR, but by then the fight should be over and our natural regeneration should tide us over), and given the natural regeneration rate of 12.5 or 17.5 on top of that, it's basically impossible to do damage fast enough to keep pace with the regeneration (an AGI team could potentially do it using hit-and-run tactics, but nobody's built one of those yet).</s> {**Update**: Apparently this combo doesn't actually work (Absorb only drains 10 HP), but the team somehow wins anyway.} Meanwhile, if the enemy *isn't* STR-primary, they won't like taking repeated 25- or 35-damage hits (and in fact may quite possibly be focused down within one of their turns); and if the enemy is INT-primary and using spells to defend themself (hi Invulnerables!), Absorb will eventually drain their MP down to the point where they can no longer afford to cast the spells. (Additionally, we have basically nothing to fear from most spells; their cooldowns are too long for their damage to outpace our regeneration. The main exceptions are Trap, which nobody's running yet, and Poison, which takes ages to wear down through 1000 or 1400 HP, but does work if the Wall doesn't beat the caster first.) True Sight is still the only ability practically capable of defeating invisible enemies (Track doesn't work because it requires the enemy to intentionally break invisibility within your LOS to use), so I had to put it on a team member out of necessity, lowering STR to fill the gap.

```java
LivingWall.java
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.*;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.*;
import fellowship.abilities.defensive.*;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.*;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.*;
import fellowship.abilities.statuses.*;
import fellowship.actions.*;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.*;
import fellowship.actions.damage.*;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.*;
import fellowship.actions.statuses.*;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;
import fellowship.characters.EnemyCharacter;
import fellowship.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class LivingWall extends Player {
  @Override
  public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
    List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(30, 0, 0,
                                          new Absorb(),
                                          new Strong(),
                                          new Buff(),
                                          new Buff()));
    templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                                        new Absorb(),
                                        new TrueSight(),
                                        new Buff(),
                                        new Buff()));

    return templates;
  }

  private String lastIdentifier(String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("\\W");
    return split[split.length - 1];
  }

  private boolean hasAbility(ReadonlyCharacter character, String abilityName) {
    for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
      if (lastIdentifier(ability.name()).equals(abilityName))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean hasAbility(EnemyCharacter character, String abilityName) {
    for (ReadonlyAbility ability : character.getAbilities()) {
      if (lastIdentifier(ability.name()).equals(abilityName))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private int goalX = 5;
  private int goalY = 5;

  @Override
  public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {

    /* If we're at the goal square, pick a new one. */
    if (goalX == character.getLocation().getX() &&
        goalY == character.getLocation().getY()) {
      int i = getRandom().nextInt(5);
      goalX = i < 2 ? 1 : i > 2 ? 9 : 5;
      goalY = i == 2 ? 5 : (i % 2) == 1 ? 1 : 9;
    }

    {
      int bestDistance = 99999;
      /* If there are visible enemies, place the goal square under the closest enemy to
         the team. */
      for (Point2D enemyLocation : visibleEnemies.keysView()) {
        int distance = 0;
        for (ReadonlyCharacter ally : team) {
          Point2D allyLocation = ally.getLocation();
          distance +=
            (allyLocation.getX() - enemyLocation.getX()) *
            (allyLocation.getX() - enemyLocation.getX()) +
            (allyLocation.getY() - enemyLocation.getY()) *
            (allyLocation.getY() - enemyLocation.getY());
        }
        if (distance < bestDistance) {
          goalX = enemyLocation.getX();
          goalY = enemyLocation.getY();
          bestDistance = distance;
        }
      }
    }

    /* We use a priority rule for actions. */
    int bestPriority = -2;
    ReadonlyAction bestAction = null;
    for (ReadonlyAction action : actions) {
      int priority = 0;
      if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Slice")) {
        int damagePotential = 35;
        /* We use these abilities with very high priority to /kill/ an enemy
           who's weak enough to die from the damage. If they wouldn't die,
           we still want to attack them, but we might prefer to attack
           other enemies instead. The enemy on the goal square (if any)
           is a slightly preferred target, to encourage the team to focus
           on a single enemy. */
        ReadonlyCharacter chosenTarget = null;
        for (ReadonlyCharacter target : action.availableTargets()) {
          if (!isEnemy(target))
            continue;
          chosenTarget = target;
          if (target.getHealth() <= damagePotential) {
            priority = 18;
          } else
            priority = 14;
          if (target.getLocation().getX() == goalX &&
              target.getLocation().getY() == goalY)
            priority++;
        }
        if (chosenTarget == null)
          continue;
        action.setTarget(chosenTarget);
      } else if (lastIdentifier(action.getName()).equals("Smile")) {
        priority = 0;
      } else if (action.movementAction()) {
        /* Move towards the goal location. */
        int bestDistance = 99999;
        Point2D bestLocation = null;
        priority = 1;
        for (Point2D location :
               action.availableLocations().toList().shuffleThis(getRandom())) {
          int distance =
            (location.getX() - goalX) * (location.getX() - goalX) +
            (location.getY() - goalY) * (location.getY() - goalY);
          if (distance < bestDistance) {
            bestDistance = distance;
            bestLocation = location;
          }
        }
        if (bestLocation == null)
          continue;
        action.setLocation(bestLocation);
      } else
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown action" + action.getName());

      if (priority > bestPriority) {
        bestPriority = priority;
        bestAction = action;
      }
    }
    if (bestAction == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("no action?");

    return bestAction;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## DarkAbsorbers

The Dark Absorbers are 2 brothers, which absorb the life force of their victims:

- **Oracle Absorber** (can see invisible enemies)

  - **STR:** 25; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 5
  - **TrueSight**, **Flexible**, **Ranged**, **Absorb**
- **Quick Absorber** (can absorb even quicker, than his brother)

  - **STR:** 25; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 5
  - **Quick**, **Flexible**, **Ranged**, **Absorb**

They are always accompanied by a growing Darkness Cloud. Once it reaches a critical mass it starts to kill enemies.

- **Darkness Cloud**

  - **STR:** 5; **AGI:** 5; **INT:** 25
  - **Clone**, **Zap**, **Darkness**

*You may reuse single characters from here in your team, as long as you add at least one more character which is not present here.*

```java
DarkAbsorbers.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.collections.api.map.ImmutableMap;
import org.eclipse.collections.api.set.ImmutableSet;

import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;

import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.ReadonlyAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Absorb;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Flexible;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Ranged;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.Darkness;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.TrueSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.actions.damage.Zap;
import fellowship.actions.defensive.ForceField;
import fellowship.actions.other.Clone;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

public class DarkAbsorbers extends SleafarPlayer {
    private ReadonlyCharacter zapTarget = null;

    private CharacterTemplate oracleAbsorberTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                new TrueSight(), new Flexible(), new Ranged(), new Absorb());
    }

    private CharacterTemplate quickAbsorberTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                new ActionAbility(Quick::new), new Flexible(), new Ranged(), new Absorb());
    }

    private CharacterTemplate darknessCloudTemplate() {
        return new CharacterTemplate(0, 0, 20,
                new ActionAbility(Clone::new), new ActionAbility(Zap::new), new Darkness());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        return Arrays.asList(oracleAbsorberTemplate(), quickAbsorberTemplate(), darknessCloudTemplate());
    }

    private class Absorber extends Character {
        protected Absorber(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction quick = getAction(Quick.class);

            if (quick != null && setSliceTarget(quick, 100.0)) {
                return quick;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 100.0)) {
                return slice;
            }

            ImmutableMap<Point2D, Double> damage = getEnemySliceDamage();
            ImmutableSet<Point2D> above5Damage = damage.select((k, v) -> v > 5.0).keysView().toSet().toImmutable();

            if (step != null && (above5Damage.contains(getLocation()) ||
                    (getHealth() <= 5.0 && isInEnemySliceRange())) && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (quick != null && setSliceTarget(quick, 0.01)) {
                return quick;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && getSliceLocations().notEmpty() && setClosestLocation(step, getSliceLocations())) {
                return step;
            }
            if (step != null && setExploreLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    private class DarknessCloud extends Character {
        private int zapCooldown = 0;
        private boolean zapNow = false;
        private boolean zapLater = false;

        protected DarknessCloud(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        private void updateZapFlags(double mana) {
            zapNow = zapCooldown == 0 && mana >= 15.0;
            zapLater = mana + 5 * getManaRegen() >= (zapNow ? 30.0 : 15.0);
        }

        private boolean isZappable(ReadonlyCharacter c, int zapNowCount, int zapLaterCount) {
            int forceFieldNow = 0;
            int forceFieldLater = 0;
            for (ReadonlyAbility a : c.getAbilities()) {
                if (a.abilityClass().equals(ForceField.class)) {
                    forceFieldNow = a.getRemaining();
                    forceFieldLater = 5;
                }
            }
            return c.getHealth() + c.getHealthRegen() <= (zapNowCount - forceFieldNow) * 30.0 ||
                    c.getHealth() + c.getHealthRegen() * 6 <= (zapNowCount + zapLaterCount - forceFieldNow - forceFieldLater) * 30.0;
        }

        @Override
        protected ReadonlyAction choose() {
            ReadonlyAction clone = getAction(Clone.class);
            ReadonlyAction zap = getAction(Zap.class);

            zapCooldown = zapCooldown > 0 ? zapCooldown - 1 : 0;
            updateZapFlags(getMana());
            int zapNowCount = characters.count(c -> c instanceof DarknessCloud && ((DarknessCloud) c).zapNow);
            int zapLaterCount = characters.count(c -> c instanceof DarknessCloud && ((DarknessCloud) c).zapLater);

            if (zap != null) {
                if (zapTarget != null && (!zap.availableTargets().contains(zapTarget) || zapTarget.isDead() ||
                        !isZappable(zapTarget, zapNowCount, zapLaterCount))) {
                    zapTarget = null;
                }
                if (zapTarget == null) {
                    zapTarget = chooseSmallest(zap.availableTargets().reject(c ->
                            isBear(c) || !isZappable(c, zapNowCount, zapLaterCount)), HEALTH_COMPARATOR);
                }
                if (zapTarget != null) {
                    zapCooldown = 5;
                    zapNow = false;
                    zap.setTarget(zapTarget);
                    return zap;
                }
            }

            ImmutableMap<Point2D, Double> damage = getEnemySliceDamage();
            ImmutableSet<Point2D> above5Damage = damage.select((k, v) -> v > 5.0).keysView().toSet().toImmutable();

            if (clone != null) {
                if (visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
                    if (setFarthestLocation(clone, getTeamHiddenLocations())) {
                        updateZapFlags(getMana() - 100.0);
                        return clone;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (setFarthestLocation(clone, above5Damage, getEnemyLocations()) ||
                            setLocation(clone, chooseSmallest(clone.availableLocations(),
                            (o1, o2) -> Double.compare(damage.get(o1), damage.get(o2))))) {
                        updateZapFlags(getMana() - 100.0);
                        return clone;
                    }
                }

                return clone;
            }
            if (step != null && (above5Damage.contains(getLocation()) ||
                    (getHealth() <= 5.0 && isInEnemySliceRange())) && setAvoidEnemiesLocation(step)) {
                return step;
            }
            if (slice != null && setSliceTarget(slice, 0.01)) {
                return slice;
            }
            if (step != null && !visibleEnemies.isEmpty() &&
                    setFarthestLocation(step, getEnemySliceLocations(), getEnemyLocations())) {
                return step;
            }
            return smile;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Character createCharacter(ReadonlyCharacter delegate) {
        if (hasAbility(delegate, Absorb.class)) {
            return new Absorber(delegate);
        } else if (hasAbility(delegate, Darkness.class)) {
            return new DarknessCloud(delegate);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## LongSwordv2

> "You can run, but you can't hide..."- **LongSwordv2**

Uses **Ranged**, **Flexible**, **Quick**, **TrueSight**

This bot is *exactly* the same as LongSwordv2, except that it uses TrueSight instead of Strong.

Seeing the rise in invisible bots, I decided to create a bot that is focused in taking them out since they are undetectable by many bots. With its long range and flexible Slice range and double Slice ActionAbility, LongSwordv2 should be able to inflict heavy damage before the enemy characters come into Slicing range. And in its testing stages, I'd say it wins against teams that are centred around invisible characters most of the time.

```java
LongSwordv2.java
import fellowship.*;
import com.nmerrill.kothcomm.game.maps.Point2D;
import fellowship.abilities.ActionAbility;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Flexible;
import fellowship.abilities.attacking.Ranged;
import fellowship.abilities.stats.Strong;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.Darkness;
import fellowship.abilities.vision.TrueSight;
import fellowship.actions.ReadonlyAction;
import fellowship.actions.attacking.Quick;
import fellowship.characters.CharacterTemplate;
import fellowship.characters.ReadonlyCharacter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class LongSwordv2 extends Player{
    //debugging
    private boolean debug = false;
    private void println(String text) {
        if(debug)
            System.out.println(text);
    }

    //variables use to hold the start Y coordinate of the bot
    private boolean started = false;
    private int startY = 5;

    private boolean together = false;

    @Override
    public List<CharacterTemplate> createCharacters() {
        List<CharacterTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            templates.add(new CharacterTemplate(20, 0, 0,
                    new Ranged(), //Adds 1 to the range of Slice
                    new Flexible(), //Can Slice in any of the 8 directions
                    new ActionAbility(Quick::new), //Slice twice, Mana: 3, Cooldown: 0
                    new TrueSight())); //Reveals all hidden units within range 2 at turn start
        }
        return templates;
    }

    @Override
    public ReadonlyAction choose(Set<ReadonlyAction> actions, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(!started) {
            startY = character.getLocation().getY(); //giving startY the value of the bot's starting y-value
            started = true; //do this only once, that's why there is the if statement
        }

        ReadonlyAction current = null;

        //choosing action depending on priority
        int priority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ReadonlyAction action:actions) {
            int priorityLocal = getPriority(action, character);
            if(priorityLocal < priority) {
                current = action;
                priority = priorityLocal;
            }
        }

        if (current == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid actions");
        }

        println(current.getName());

        if(current.needsLocation()) {
            if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
                if (character.getHealth() < 100) {
                    //if has low health, go backwards towards "base"
                    //println("lowHealth");
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "backward"));
                } else {
                    //else go forwards to enemy's "base"
                    current.setLocation(move(current, character, "forward"));
                }
            }else{
                //go towards closest enemy
                current.setLocation(current.availableLocations().minBy(p1->p1.cartesianDistance(visibleEnemies.keysView().minBy(p1::cartesianDistance))));
            }
        }
        if(current.needsTarget()) {
            //get closest target
            current.setTarget(current.availableTargets().minBy(p1 -> 0));
        }

        Iterator<ReadonlyCharacter> iterator = current.availableTargets().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Point2D loc = iterator.next().getLocation();
            println(loc.getX()+","+loc.getY());
        }

        return current;
    }

    //move backwards or forwards
    private Point2D move(ReadonlyAction readonlyAction, ReadonlyCharacter character, String direction) {
        Point2D location = null;

        //move direction depending on Y coordinate of point
        for(Point2D point2D:readonlyAction.availableLocations()) {
            switch (direction) {
                case "forward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot started at top
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
                case "backward":
                    if(startY > 5) { //bot started at bottom
                        if (point2D.getY() > character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }else{ //bot started at top
                        if (point2D.getY() < character.getLocation().getY())
                            location = point2D;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

        //if no available locations, just choose the first available location
        if(location == null) {
            location = readonlyAction.availableLocations().iterator().next();
        }

        println(location.getY()+","+character.getLocation().getY());

        return location;
    }

    private int getPriority(ReadonlyAction action, ReadonlyCharacter character) {
        if(visibleEnemies.isEmpty()) {
            //if there are no visible enemies, Step. In the choose function, this becomes move forward or backward depending on health
            if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 100;
            }
        }else {
            /*
             * PRIORITIES:
             *  1. Quick (Slice twice)
             *  2. Slice
             *  3. Step (when enemy is not in range --> move towards enemy)
             */
            if (action.getName().equals("Quick")) {
                return 1;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Slice")) {
                return 10;
            }else if(action.getName().equals("Step")) {
                return 50;
            }
        }
        //Kids, don't Smile, instead Step or Slice
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downloading this bot fails, because the header is missing.

Comment: @Sleafar There we go... added it!